# How do I get a div to float to the bottom of its container?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have floated images and inset boxes at the top of a container using `float:right` (or `left`) many times. Now, I need to float a `div` to the bottom right corner of another `div` with the normal text wrap that you get with `float` (text wrapped above and to the left only).

I thought this must be relatively easy even though `float` has no `bottom` value but I haven't been able to do it using a number of techniques and searching the web hasn't come up with anything other than using absolute positioning but this doesn't give the correct word wrap behaviour.

I had thought this would be a very common design but apparently it isn't. If nobody has a suggestion I'll have to break my text up into separate boxes and align the `div` manually but that is rather precarious and I'd hate to have to do it on every page that needs it.

Comment: I'll work on this "float to the bottom" issue just as soon as i figure out how to make something sink to the top... ;-)

Comment: @Shog9 conclusion: css needs a "sink" element.

Comment: Most of the answers here disregard the requirement for text to wrap around and above the "sunk" element. But Stu's answer works (with JQuery).

Comment: I don't see it that funny, I would like to know how do you manage to float to the right or left in real life first.... It is totally floating in a z-axes   point of view.

Comment: Using flexboxes - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27812717/2680216

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I position my div at the bottom of its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/how-can-i-position-my-div-at-the-bottom-of-its-container)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After struggling with various techniques for a couple of days I have to say that this appears to be impossible. Even using javascript (which I don't want to do) it doesn't seem possible.

To clarify for those who may not have understood - this is what I am looking for: in publishing it is quite common to layout an inset (picture, table, figure, etc.) so that its bottom lines up with the bottom of the last line of text of a block (or page) with text flowing around the inset in a natural manner above and to the right or left depending on which side of the page the inset is on. In html/css it is trivial to use the float style to line up the top of an inset with the top of a block but to my surprise it appears impossible to line up the bottom of the text and inset despite it being a common layout task.

I guess I'll have to revisit the design goals for this item unless anyone has a last minute suggestion.

Comment: Nope - this is not print publishing. There are some things that are extraordinarily difficult or impossible to accomplish using just html/css.

Comment: I know this is pretty dang old now, but this version of the question is what popped up when I had the same problem and I solved it by using display: flex and setting a top container with a very high flex-grow  amount and the container I wanted floated to the bottom as simply flex-grow: 1. And of course the grow direction needs to be column.

Comment: @Alexandra does the bottom right box push the text around its corners like normal floats do? "Text flow" is one of OP's requirements

Comment: I had encountered problems like this before and I use the CSS grid to pull it off. If only you had attached a visual representation of the problem. This question would have maybe been answered 11 years after the CSS Grid came in to save us.

Comment: @Rakushoe Can you share the solution with css grid? I've been trying to solve it but no luck.

Comment: I now it's quite old question and answer. Now you can do it, see
https://css-tricks.com/float-an-element-to-the-bottom-corner/

Answer (score 331):

Set the parent div to `position: relative`, then the inner div to...

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
```

...and there you go :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was the way to go also but when you set the position to absolute the element no longer participates in the layout of the containing element, so there is no word wrap and the text in the bottom corner is obscured.

Comment: Maybe you could use a combination of a floated containing div with the position relative and absolute technique.

Comment: Setting the float to right and then applying e.g. a negative top relative position, leads to the image being pushed over/under the text render before in the container before that image.

Comment: position absolute was mentioned as unacceptable solution, unfortunately

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work.   It positions to the bottom of the whole page instead.

Comment: @dylanfm I came up with a solution featuring a hidden floated span and a visible absolutely positioned span. The result is satisfying. Not sure if that's what you were thinking. Anyway, I posted an answer below.

Comment: @ErikAronesty Absolute positioned element look for nearest relative positioned container to get it's position. But if immediate parent container does not set to relative position, it goes to next parent and so on.

Comment: @ErikAronestyYou definitely need the relative position on the parent

Answer (score 81):

A way to make it work is the following:

- Float your elements left like normal
- Rotate the parent div 180 degrees using

  ```
  -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
  ```

  JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wcneY/
- Now rotate all the elements that float left (give them a class) 180 degrees to put them straight again. Voila! they float to the bottom.

Comment: This is the best solution, because you can keep the dynamic height from your content! Thanks

Comment: While it is an amazing solution, it messes up my Firefox Nightly developer tools: The div picker seems to ignore the rotated divs and everything inside them.

Comment: Unable to wrap text around the bottom right box: all letters turn upside down, and read(?) from bottom to top. http://jsfiddle.net/xu8orw5L/

Comment: This is insane man! it works if you don't matter about having everything upside-down

Comment: This is the devils work and I am using it immediately.

Comment: next level. next. level.

Comment: Just FYI, as of 2019 the jsfiddle is is not working anymore at all in Firefox and Chrome (even if you remove the prefixes).

Answer (score 16):

I have acheived this in JQuery  by putting  a zero width strut element above the float right, then sizing the strut (or pipe) according to parent height minus floated child's height.

Before js kicks in I am using the position absolute approach, which works but allows text flow behind.  Therefore I switch to position static to enable the strut approach.
(header is the parent element, cutout is the one i want bottom right, and pipe is my strut)

```
$("header .pipe").each(function(){
    $(this).next(".cutout").css("position","static");       
    $(this).height($(this).parent().height()-$(this).next(".cutout").height());                                                 
});
```

CSS

```
header{
    position: relative; 
}

header img.cutout{
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    clear:right
}
header .pipe{
    width:0px; 
    float:right

}
```

The pipe must come 1st, then the cutout, then the text in the HTML order.

Comment: It's a lot of work and using javascript for styling is always a last-ditch fallback because it gets messed up so easily if you change your css later on. But yes, this does work, so if it's crucial to have that div line up at the bottom with word wrap: go for it.

Comment: This worked for me, but I couldn't get it to be exact. I suppose .height() may be the culprit there. Seems when there is a lot of block-level text (like multiple divs and paragraphs) wrapping around the floating block, .height() gets a little variable depending on how the text breaks lines.

Comment: I went the other way and checked the width of the container (header) and the one piece of content I had to wrap around (logo) and set a max-width on the absolutely positioned content (navigation). No floats and no extra elements. Still have JS and depends on knowing what you need to wrap around.

Comment: This works.  Just remember to make it a window resize handler as well.  And I had to manually subtract the inner box's margins.

Answer (score 14):

This puts a fixed div at the bottom of the page and fixes to the bottom as you scroll down

```
#div {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what he's trying to do. @Timoty and @Yona got it right.

Answer (score 11):

Put the div in another div and set the parent div's style to `position:relative;` Then on the child div set the following CSS properties: `position:absolute; bottom:0;`

Comment: See my comment to Timothy. As you can see here: http://www.emsoft.ca/absolutebottomtest.html the word wrap doesn't work. And some of the content is obscured.

Comment: This is the perfect solution if you don't need any text inside the child div.

Comment: Unfortunately, text-wrap doesn't work with this solution as @Stephen Martin mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

If you set the parent element as position:relative, you can set the child to the bottom setting position:absolute; and bottom:0;

```css
#outer {
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative; 
}

#inner {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:white; 
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <h1>done</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

With the introduction of [**Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), this has become quite easy without much hacking. [`align-self: flex-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) on the child element will align it along the [cross-axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model).

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bottom">Bottom of the container</div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* Material design shadow */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  height: 100px;
  width: 175px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bottom">Bottom of the container</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have read the question thoroughly.. Positioning it to the bottom is easy, but that doesn't give the desired floating behaviour.

Comment: I can't, as I unfortunately don't have an answer and don't see sth. else wrong with the answer, that would need correction.

Comment: @Dennis98 I agree with your comment. This is a wrong answer for the question. What can we do? :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're okay with only the bottom-most line of the text going to the side of the block (as opposed to completely around and underneath it, which you can't do without ending the block and starting a new one), it's not impossible to float a block to one of the bottom corners of a parent block. If you put some content in a paragraph tag within a block and want to float a link to the bottom right corner of the block, put the link within the paragraph block and set it to float: right, then put in a div tag with clear: both set just underneath the end of the paragraph tag. The last div is to make sure the parent tag surrounds the floated tags.

```
<div class="article" style="display: block;">
    <h3>title</h3>
        <p>
            text content
            <a href="#" style="display: block;float: right;">Read More</a>
        </p>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had been find this solution for a long time as well.
This is what I get:

align-self: flex-end;

link: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/
However, I can't remember from where I opened this link. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

If you want the text to wrap nicely:-

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
}

.inner {
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* Just for styling */
.inner {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Need two parent elements -->
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3>Sample Heading</h3>
    <p>Sample Paragragh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this stuff is old, but I recently ran into this problem.

*use absolute position divs* advice is really silly, because the whole float thing kind of loses point with absolute positions..

now, I did not find an universal solution, but in a lot of cases prople use floating divs just to display something in a row, like a series of span elements. and you can't vertically align that.

to achieve a similar effect you can do this: do not make the div float, but set it's display property to `inline-block`. then you can align it vertically however it pleases you. you just need to set parent's div property `vertical-align` to either `top`, `bottom`, `middle` or `baseline`

i hope that helps someone

Comment: No idea if this works in common situations, but with jQueryMobile it's completely non-functional.

Comment: this is exactly what is needed for aligning the div to bottom or side by side, great help

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible with flex box.
Just set the 'display' of parent div as 'flex' and set the 'margin-top' property to 'auto'.
This does not distort any property of both the div.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #0f0f0f;
}
.child {
  margin-top: auto;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 40px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class=" parent">
  <div class="child">I am at the bottom!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: Image floated to the bottom of a paragraph]

Currently this is not possible. There are different approaches to solve aligning content to the bottom edge (flex, grid, table, absolute). However these approaches don't respect float and thus the content does not flow around these elements.

Someday floating elements could be possible with css if browsers and the csswg agrees on a definition.

#### Advanced resources:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-floats/#float-property

https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1251

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/float-an-element-to-the-bottom-corner/ seems to disagree but I haven't understood the details

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but a scenario posted earlier seemed to work if you use **position: relative** instead of absolute on the child div.

```
#parent {
  width: 780px;
  height: 250px;
  background: yellow;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
#child {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 780px;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: blue;
  border: solid 2px green;
}
```

```
<div id="parent">
    This has some text in it.

    <div id="child">
        This is just some text to show at the bottom of the page
    </div>
</div>
```

And no tables...!

Answer (score 1):

One interesting approach is to stack a couple of right float elements on top of each other.

```
<div>
<div style="float:right;height:200px;"></div>
<div style="float:right;clear:right;">Floated content</div>
<p>Other content</p>
</div>
```

Only problem is that this only works when you know the height of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a table.

```
<div class="elastic">
  <div class="elastic_col valign-bottom">
    bottom-aligned content.
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.elastic {
  display: table;
}
.elastic_col {
  display: table-cell;
}
.valign-bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

See it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/mLphM/1/

Answer (score 1):

I tried several of these techniques, and the following worked for me, so if all else here if all else fails then try this because it worked for me :).

```
<style>
  #footer {
    height:30px;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom:-10;
  }
</style>

<div id="footer" >Sportkin - the registry for sport</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A chose this approach of @dave-kok. But it works only if the whole content suits without scrolling. I appreciate if somebody will improve

```
outer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.space {
    float: right;
    height: 75%;  
}
.floateable {
    width: 40%;
    height: 25%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;  
 }
```

Here is code  http://jsfiddle.net/d9t9joh2/

Answer (score 1):

To use css `margin-top` property with purpose to set footer to the bottom of its container. And to use css  `text-align-last` property to set the footer contents at center.

```
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 700px;  text-align-last: center; ">
      <p>My footer Here</p>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of floating and absolute positioning does the work for me. I was attempting to place the send time of a message at the bottom-right corner of the speech bubble. The time should never overlap the message body and it will not inflate the bubble unless it's really necessary.

The solution works like this:

1. there're two spans with identical text;
2. one is floated but invisible;
3. the other is absolutely positioned to the corner;

The purpose of the invisible floated one is to ensure space for the visible one.

```css
.speech-bubble {
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 240px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.inline-time {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.giant-text {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.tremendous-giant-text {
  font-size: 72px;
}

.absolute-time {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      This text is supposed to wrap the time &lt;span&gt; which always seats at the corner of this bubble.
      <span class='inline-time'>13:55</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      Absolute positioning doesn't work because it doesn't care if the two pieces of text overlap. We want to float.
      <span class='inline-time'>13:55</span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      Easy, uh?
      <span class='inline-time'>13:55</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      Well, not <span class='giant-text'>THAT</span>
      easy
      <span class='inline-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      <span class='tremendous-giant-text'>See?</span>
      <span class='inline-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      The problem is, we can't tell the span to float to right AND bottom...
      <span class='inline-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      We can combinate float and absolute: use floated span to reserve space (the bubble will be inflated if necessary) so that the absoluted span is safe to go.
      <span class='inline-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      <span class='tremendous-giant-text'>See?</span>
      <span class='inline-time'>13:56</span>
      <span class='absolute-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      Make the floated span invisible.
      <span class='inline-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      <span class='tremendous-giant-text'>See?</span>
      <span class='inline-time hidden'>13:56</span>
      <span class='absolute-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <span class='speech-bubble'>
      The giant text here is to simulate images which are common in a typical chat app.
      <span class='tremendous-giant-text'>Done!</span>
      <span class='inline-time hidden'>13:56</span>
      <span class='absolute-time'>13:56</span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right solution:

```
.toBottomRight
{
  display:inline-block;
  position:fixed;
  left:100%;
  top:100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  white-space:nowrap;
  background:red;
}

<div class="toBottomRight">Bottom-Right</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/2k85qzxv/9/

Answer (score 0):

If you need relative alignment and DIV's still aren't give you what you want, just use tables and set valign = "bottom" in the cell you want the content aligned to the bottom.  I know it's not a great answer to your question since DIV's are supposed to replace tables, but this is what I had to do recently with an image caption and it has worked flawlessly so far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this scenario posted earlier also;

```
div {
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100px; 
  top: 100%; 
  margin-top:-100px; 
}
```

The absolute positioning fixes the div to the lowest part of the browser upon loading the page, but when you scroll down if the page is longer it does not scroll with you. I changed the positioning to be relative and it works perfect. The div goes straight to the bottom upon load so you won't actually see it until you get to the bottom.

```
div {
      position: relative;
      height:100px; /* Or the height of your image */
      top: 100%;
      margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Any way to make it work with an unknown height? Unfortunately margin-top: -100%; refers to container height I am guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Stu's answer comes the closest to working so far, but it still doesn't take into account the fact that your outer div's height may change, based on the way the text wraps inside of it. So, repositioning the inner div (by changing the height of the "pipe") only once won't be enough. That change has to occur inside of a loop, so you can continually check whether you've achieved the right positioning yet, and readjust if needed.

The CSS from the previous answer is still perfectly valid:

```
#outer {
    position: relative; 
}

#inner {
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    clear:right
}

.pipe {
    width:0px; 
    float:right

}
```

However, the Javascript should look more like this:

```
var innerBottom;
var totalHeight;
var hadToReduce = false;
var i = 0;
jQuery("#inner").css("position","static");
while(true) {

    // Prevent endless loop
    i++;
    if (i > 5000) { break; }

    totalHeight = jQuery('#outer').outerHeight();
    innerBottom = jQuery("#inner").position().top + jQuery("#inner").outerHeight();
    if (innerBottom < totalHeight) {
        if (hadToReduce !== true) { 
            jQuery(".pipe").css('height', '' + (jQuery(".pipe").height() + 1) + 'px');
        } else { break; }
    } else if (innerBottom > totalHeight) {
        jQuery(".pipe").css('height', '' + (jQuery(".pipe").height() - 1) + 'px');
        hadToReduce = true;
    } else { break; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old thread but still I would like to answer. If anyone follow the below css & html then it works. The child footer div will stick with bottom like glue.

```
<style>
        #MainDiv
        {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: Red;
            position: relative;
        }

        #footerDiv
        {
            height: 50px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: green;
            float: right;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
        }
    </style>


<div id="MainDiv">
     <div id="footerDiv">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is very complicated but it is possible. I have check this code on latest Firefox and Google Chrome browser. Older browser may not support the css `shape-outside` property. For further detail [check this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside).

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var imageHolder = document.querySelector('.image-holder');

  var containerHeight = document.querySelector('.container').offsetHeight;

  var imageHolderHeight = imageHolder.offsetHeight;

  var countPadding = containerHeight - imageHolderHeight;
  imageHolder.style.paddingTop = countPadding + 'px';
  containerHeight = document.querySelector('.container').offsetHeight;
  var x1 = '0' + 'px ' + countPadding + 'px';

  var x2 = imageHolder.offsetWidth + 'px' + ' ' + countPadding + 'px';

  var x3 = imageHolder.offsetWidth + 'px' + ' ' + containerHeight + 'px';

  var x4 = 0 + 'px' + ' ' + containerHeight + 'px';

  var value = 'polygon(' + x1 + ',' + x2 + ',' + x3 + ',' + x4 + ')';

  imageHolder.style.shapeOutside = value;

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-holder {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' style="">
  <div class='image-holder' style=''>
    <img class='bottom-right' style="width: 100px;" src="https://www.lwb.org.au/services/child-youth-and-family/static/b5cca79df7320248a77f6655a278190f/a6c62/img-index-banner.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quasi ut ipsam saepe, dignissimos, accusamus debitis ratione neque doloribus quis exercitationem iure! Harum quisquam ipsam velit distinctio tempora repudiandae eveniet.</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With some JavaScript I managed to pin a floated element to the bottom of its container - and still have it floated in the text, which is very useful for things like shape-outside.

The floated element gets a margin-top assigned that is equal to its container, its own height subtracted. This preserves the float, pushes the element to the bottom edge of its container and prevents text flowing below the element.

```js
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  if(entries.length == 0) return;
  const entry = entries[0];
  if(!entry.contentRect) return;

  const containerHeight = entry.contentRect.height;
  const imgHeight = imgElem.height;
  const imgOffset = containerHeight - imgHeight;
  
  imgElem.style.marginTop = imgOffset + 'px';
});

const imgElem = document.querySelector('.image');
resizeObserver.observe(imgElem.parentElement);
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/strarsis/pen/QWGXGVy

Thanks to ResizeObserver and widespread support for JavaScript this seems to be a very reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS+Javascript solution.  Start with a top right floating div.  Then calculate the height for a zero-width div along the right edge to push your floating div to the bottom.  This code may need some tweaking to get the right height.

```
<style>
  #mainbox {border:4px solid red;width:500px;padding:10px;}
  .rightpad {float:right;clear:right;padding:0;width:0;}
  #floater {background-color:red;text-align:center;color:#FFF;width:300px;height:100px;float:right;margin-right:-10px;margin-top:10px;}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var mmheight = document.getElementById("mainbox").clientHeight;
  var ff = document.getElementById("floater");
  var ffheight = ff.clientHeight;
  var dd = document.createElement('div');
  dd.className = "rightpad";
  dd.style.height = (mmheight - ffheight - 20) * 1 + "px";
  ff.parentNode.insertBefore(dd,ff);
}
</script>
<div id="mainbox">
  <div id="floater" class="rightpad">123</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam posuere tellus et dolor vestibulum gravida. Donec vel nunc massa. Quisque quis varius libero. Fusce ut elementum magna. Praesent hendrerit diam sed velit rutrum mollis. Nunc pretium metus in tempus tempus. Quisque laoreet nibh eget volutpat dictum. Pellentesque libero ipsum, tristique et aliquam aliquam, accumsan sed sem. Phasellus facilisis sem eget mi tempus rhoncus.</p></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty old question, but still ...
You can float a div to the bottom of the page like this:

```
div{
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100px; 
  top: 100%; 
  margin-top:-100px; 
}
```

You can see where the magic happens. I think you could do the same for floating it to the bottom of a parent div.

Comment: This doesn't wrap text around it, though. Any text appears behind it.

Comment: Yes, this is not "floated" in the CSS sense of the word. It's "moved" but not floated.

Answer (score -2):

I got this to work on the first try by adding `position:absolute; bottom:0;` to the div ID inside the CSS. I did not add the parent style `position:relative;`.

It is working perfect in both Firefox and IE 8, have not tried it in IE 7 yet.

Answer (score -2):

an alternative answer is the judicious use of tables and rowspan. by setting all table cells on the preceeding line (except the main content one) to be rowspan="2" you will always get a one cell hole at the bottom of your main table cell that you can always put valign="bottom".

You can also set its height to be the minimum you need for one line. Thus you will always get your favourite line of text at the bottom regardless of how much space the rest of the text takes up.

I tried all the div answers, I was unable to get them to do what I needed.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td valign="top">
     this is just some random text
     <br> that should be a couple of lines long and
     <br> is at the top of where we need the bottom tag line
   </td>
   <td rowspan="2">
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     this<br/>
     is really<br/>
     tall
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="bottom">
      now this is the tagline we need on the bottom
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Table based design is considered bad practice amongst most web developers. CSS is preferred for styling a page, and you can accomplish the same things in a much more semantic friendly manner.

Comment: Tables are not very multi-format friendly (print, screen, mobile), they have no flow to them. Just offering an alternative.

Answer (score -2):

here is my solution:

```
<style>
.sidebar-left{float:left;width:200px}
.content-right{float:right;width:700px}

.footer{clear:both;position:relative;height:1px;width:900px}
.bottom-element{position:absolute;top:-200px;left:0;height:200px;}

</style>

<div class="sidebar-left"> <p>content...</p></div>
<div class="content-right"> <p>content content content content...</p></div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="bottom-element">bottom-element-in-sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

simple......in the html file right....have the "footer" (or the div you want at the bottom) at the bottom. So dont do this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="Footer"></div>
    <div id="Content"></div>
    <div id="Sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

DO THIS: (have the footer underneath.)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="Content"></div>
    <div id="Sidebar"></div>
    <div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
```

After doing this then you can go the css file and have the "sidebar" float to the left. then have "content" float to the right then have "footer" clear both.

that should work.did for me.

Answer (score -2):

Oh, youngsters.... Here you are:

```
<div class="block">
    <a href="#">Some Content with a very long description. Could be a Loren Ipsum or something like that.</a>
    <span>
        <span class="r-b">A right-bottom-block with some information</span>
    </span>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
<style>
    .block {
        border: #000 solid 1px;
    }

    .r-b {
        border: #f00 solid 1px;
        background-color: fuchsia;
        float: right;
        width: 33%
    }

    .clearfix::after {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        content: "";
    }
</style>
```

No absolute position!
Responsive!
OldSchool

Answer (score -3):

You could try using an empty element with a 1px width and floating it. Then clear the element you actually want to position and use the height of the empty element to control how far down it goes.

http://codepen.io/cssgrid/pen/KNYrey/

```
.invisible {
float: left;  
}

.bottom {
float: left;
padding-right: 35px;
padding-top: 30px;
clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

To put any element at the bottom of its container, just used this:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Just that and it may end up at the bottom of the screen. The parent div needs to have `position: relative` too.