# How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, each

I have a JavaScript object like the following:

```
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};
```

How do I loop through all of `p`'s elements (`p1`, `p2`, `p3`...) and get their keys and values?

Answer (score 5163, accepted):

You can use the [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop as shown by others. However, you also have to make sure that the key you get is an actual property of an object, and doesn't come from the prototype.

**Here is the snippet:**

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
    }
}
```

**For-of with Object.keys() alternative:**

```js
var p = {
    0: "value1",
    "b": "value2",
    key: "value3"
};

for (var key of Object.keys(p)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key])
}
```

Notice the use of [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), if not used it will return undefined on named properties, and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ensures the use of only the object's own properties without the whole prototype-chain properties

**Using the new [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method:**

**Note:** This method is not supported natively by Internet Explorer. You may consider using a Polyfill for older browsers.

```js
const p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(p)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: In javascript, every object has a bunch of built-in key-value pairs that have meta-information.  When you loop through all the key-value pairs for an object you're looping through them too.  hasOwnPropery() filters these out.

Comment: Actually, [For...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is not deprecated.  [For each...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) is.  But I really like the term _archaeologists_...I'm going to have to start using that.

Comment: How can I add the values that was looped? Thanks

Comment: (for..in) for objects, (for.. of) for arrays

Comment: is it possible to even do this using while loops? 
like while(let x in objectA || objectA[x].hasOwnProperty("childPointer")

Comment: I rember the diff between `of` and `in` in `for` loops with: Better to use `of`,but more practical is `in` because of no need for `Object.entries()`. Is `hasOwnProperty` also recommended in `for..of`?

Comment: for anyone concerned about performance, `for..in` + `hasOwnProperty` is marginally faster in normal use (https://jsben.ch/pCDAk), with `Object.keys` being significantly faster beyond a few thousand properties (https://jsben.ch/ptzsL).

Answer (score 1372):

Under ECMAScript 5, you can combine [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var obj = { first: "John", last: "Doe" };

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

ECMAScript 6 adds [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

ECMAScript 8 adds [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which avoids having to look up each value in the original object:

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => console.log(key, value)
);
```

You can combine `for...of`, destructuring, and `Object.entries`:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Both `Object.keys()` and `Object.entries()` iterate properties in the same order as a `for...in` loop *but ignore the prototype chain*. Only the object's own enumerable properties are iterated.

Comment: Why didn't the standard provide `Object.forEach(obj, function (value, key) {...})`? :( Certainly `obj.forEach(function...)` would be shorter and complement `Array.prototype.forEach`, but that would risk having objects define their own `forEach` property. I suppose `Object.keys` guards against the callback modifying the object's keys.

Comment: Python is so easy, javascript I have to look up basics every time.

Answer (score 377):

You have to use the **for-in loop**

But be very careful when using this kind of loop, because this will **loop all the properties along the prototype chain**.

Therefore, when using for-in loops, always make use of the `hasOwnProperty` method to determine if the current property in iteration is really a property of the object you're checking on:

```
for (var prop in p) {
    if (!p.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        //The current property is not a direct property of p
        continue;
    }
    //Do your logic with the property here
}
```

Comment: This is better than levik's solution because it allows the main logic to be only one nested loop in rather than two; making for easier to read code. Although I'd loose the the brackets around the continue; they are superfluous.

Comment: I would not remove the `{ }` personally because an `if` without them makes it a little unclear what is part of the `if` and what is not. But I guess that's just a matter of opinion :)

Comment: Yes, I prefer keeping the `{ }` mainly to avoid confusion if one later on needs to add something to the `if` scope.

Comment: Reading my previous comment, I realized that I didn't use the correct terms, because I said "if scope"; but keep in mind that JavaScript only has function scope.  So what I actually meant was "if block".

Answer (score 267):

The question won't be complete if we don't mention about alternative methods for looping through objects.

Nowadays many well known JavaScript libraries provide their own methods for iterating over collections, i.e. over *arrays*, *objects*, and *array-like objects*. These methods are convenient to use and are entirely compatible with any browser.

1. If you work with **jQuery**, you may use [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method. It can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays:

   ```
   $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
       console.log(key, value);
   });
   ```
2. In **Underscore.js** you can find method [`_.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each), which iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to a supplied function (pay attention to the order of arguments in *iteratee* function!):

   ```
   _.each(obj, function(value, key) {
       console.log(key, value);
   });
   ```
3. **Lo-Dash** provides several methods for iterating over object properties. Basic [`_.forEach()`](http://lodash.com/docs#forEach) (or it's alias `_.each()`) is useful for looping through both objects and arrays, however (!) objects with `length` property are treated like arrays, and to avoid this behavior it is suggested to use [`_.forIn()`](http://lodash.com/docs#forIn) and [`_.forOwn()`](http://lodash.com/docs#forOwn) methods (these also have `value` argument coming first):

   ```
   _.forIn(obj, function(value, key) {
       console.log(key, value);
   });
   ```

   `_.forIn()` iterates over *own and inherited* enumerable properties of an object, while `_.forOwn()` iterates only over *own* properties of an object (basically checking against `hasOwnProperty` function). For simple objects and object literals any of these methods will work fine.

Generally all described methods have the same behaviour with any supplied objects. Besides using native `for..in` loop will usually be *faster* than any abstraction, such as `jQuery.each()`, these methods are considerably easier to use, require less coding and provide better error handling.

Comment: To get to the value: 

$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value.title);
});

Comment: Just funny how underscore and jquery changed parameters :)

Answer (score 72):

Preface:

- Object properties can be *own* (the property is on the object itself) or *inherited* (not on the object itself, on one of its prototypes).
- Object properties can be *enumerable* or *non-enumerable*. Non-enumerable properties are left out of lots of property enumerations/arrays.
- Property names can be strings or Symbols. Properties whose names are Symbols are left out of lots of property enumerations/arrays.

Here in 2018, your options for looping through an object's properties are (some examples follow the list):

1. **`for-in`** [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements)] — A loop structure that loops through the names of an object's *enumerable* properties, including inherited ones, whose names are strings
2. **`Object.keys`** [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.keys)] — A function providing an array of the names of an object's *own*, *enumerable* properties whose names are strings.
3. **`Object.values`** [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.values)] — A function providing an array of the *values* of an object's *own*, *enumerable* properties.
4. **`Object.entries`** [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.entries)] — A function providing an array of the names *and* values of an object's *own*, *enumerable* properties (each entry in the array is a `[name, value]` array).
5. **`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`** [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.getownpropertynames)] — A function providing an array of the names of an object's *own* properties (even non-enumerable ones) whose names are strings.
6. **`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`** [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.getownpropertysymbols)] — A function providing an array of the names of an object's *own* properties (even non-enumerable ones) whose names are Symbols.
7. **`Reflect.ownKeys`** [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-reflect.ownkeys)] — A function providing an array of the names of an object's *own* properties (even non-enumerable ones), whether those names are strings or Symbols.
8. If you want **all** of an object's properties, including non-enumerable inherited ones, you need to use a loop and `Object.getPrototypeOf` [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.getprototypeof)] and use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`, or `Reflect.ownKeys` on each object in the prototype chain (example at the bottom of this answer).

With all of them except `for-in`, you'd use some kind of looping construct on the array (`for`, `for-of`, `forEach`, etc.).

Examples:

**`for-in`:**

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (const name in o) {
    const value = o[name];
    console.log(`${name} = ${value}`);
}
```

**`Object.keys`** *(with a `for-of` loop, but you can use any looping construct)*:

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (const name of Object.keys(o)) {
    const value = o[name];
    console.log(`${name} = ${value}`);
}
```

**`Object.values`:**

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (const value of Object.values(o)) {
    console.log(`${value}`);
}
```

**`Object.entries`:**

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
    console.log(`${name} = ${value}`);
}
```

**`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:**

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
    const value = o[name];
    console.log(`${name} = ${value}`);
}
```

**`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`:**

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(o)) {
    const value = o[name];
    console.log(`${String(name)} = ${value}`);
}
```

**`Reflect.ownKeys`:**

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (const name of Reflect.ownKeys(o)) {
    const value = o[name];
    console.log(`${String(name)} = ${value}`);
}
```

**All properties**, including inherited non-enumerable ones:

```js
// A prototype object to inherit from, with a string-named property
const p = {answer: 42};
// The object we'll look at, which inherits from `p`
const o = Object.create(p);
// A string-named property
o.question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
// A symbol-named property
o[Symbol("author")] = "Douglas Adams";
for (let depth = 0, current = o; current; ++depth, current = Object.getPrototypeOf(current)) {
    for (const name of Reflect.ownKeys(current)) {
        const value = o[name];
        console.log(`[${depth}] ${String(name)} = ${String(value)}`);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Nice addition of enumerable/non-enumberable object properties.

Answer (score 63):

You can just iterate over it like:

```
for (var key in p) {
  alert(p[key]);
}
```

Note that `key` will not take on the value of the property, it's just an index value.

Comment: This is repeated and not even entirely correct. You need to have a check of hasOwnProperty to make this work properly

Comment: I initially downvoted this based on the above comment until i realized that this answer came first, therefore is not "repeated".  It is possibly incomplete but works just fine for many cases.

Answer (score 58):

In ECMAScript 5 you have new approach in iteration fields of literal - `Object.keys`

More information you can see on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

My choice is below as a faster solution in current versions of browsers (Chrome30, IE10, FF25)

```
var keys = Object.keys(p),
    len = keys.length,
    i = 0,
    prop,
    value;
while (i < len) {
    prop = keys[i];
    value = p[prop];
    i += 1;
}
```

You can compare performance of this approach with different implementations on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/):

- [Extend Implementations](http://jsperf.com/extendimplementations/2)
- [Object keys iteration](http://jsperf.com/object-keys-iteration/30)
- [object literal iteration](http://jsperf.com/object-literal-iteration/5)

Browser support you can see on [Kangax's compat table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.keys)

For old browser you have [simple](http://tokenposts.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/javascript-objectkeys-browser.html) and [full](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) polyfill

**UPD:**

performance comparison for all most popular cases in this question on `perfjs.info`:

[object literal iteration](http://perfjs.info/#!/384A61CA-DA2E-4FD2-A113-080010D4A42B)

Answer (score 48):

### Performance

Today 2020.03.06 I perform tests of chosen solutions on Chrome v80.0, Safari v13.0.5 and Firefox 73.0.1 on MacOs High Sierra v10.13.6

#### Conclusions

- solutions based on `for-in` (A,B) are fast (or fastest) for all browsers for big and small objects
- surprisingly `for-of` (H) solution is fast on chrome for small and big objects
- solutions based on explicit index `i` (J,K) are quite fast on all browsers for small objects (for firefox also fast for big ojbects but medium fast on other browsers)
- solutions based on iterators (D,E) are slowest and not recommended
- solution C is slow for big objects and medium-slow for small objects

[image]

#### Details

Performance tests was performed for

- small object - with 3 fields - you can perform test on your machine [HERE](https://jsbench.me/wok7em87k8/1)
- 'big' object - with 1000 fields - you can perform test on your machine [HERE](https://jsbench.me/0pk7emfoy9/1)

Below snippets presents used solutions

```js
function A(obj,s='') {
 for (let key in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) s+=key+'->'+obj[key] + ' ';
  return s;
}

function B(obj,s='') {
 for (let key in obj) s+=key+'->'+obj[key] + ' ';
  return s;
}

function C(obj,s='') {
  const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));
 for (let [key,value] of map) s+=key+'->'+value + ' ';
  return s;
}

function D(obj,s='') {
  let o = { 
    ...obj,
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      for (const i of Object.keys(this)) yield [i, this[i]];    
    }
  }
  for (let [key,value] of o) s+=key+'->'+value + ' ';
  return s;
}

function E(obj,s='') {
  let o = { 
    ...obj,
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {yield *Object.keys(this)}
  }
  for (let key of o) s+=key+'->'+o[key] + ' ';
  return s;
}

function F(obj,s='') {
 for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ';
  return s;
}

function G(obj,s='') {
 for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) s+=key+'->'+value+' ';
  return s;
}

function H(obj,s='') {
 for (let key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ';
  return s;
}

function I(obj,s='') {
 for (const key of Reflect.ownKeys(obj)) s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ';
  return s;
}

function J(obj,s='') {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
 for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    let key = keys[i];
    s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ';
  }
  return s;
}

function K(obj,s='') {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj), len = keys.length, i = 0;
  while (i < len) {
    let key = keys[i];
    s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ';
    i += 1;
  }
  return s;
}

function L(obj,s='') {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=> s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ' );
  return s;
}

function M(obj,s='') {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => s+=key+'->'+value+' ');
  return s;
}

function N(obj,s='') {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(key => s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ');
  return s;
}

function O(obj,s='') {
  Reflect.ownKeys(obj).forEach(key=> s+=key+'->'+obj[key]+' ' );
  return s;
}



// TEST

var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};
let log = (name,f) => console.log(`${name} ${f(p)}`)

log('A',A);
log('B',B);
log('C',C);
log('D',D);
log('E',E);
log('F',F);
log('G',G);
log('H',H);
log('I',I);
log('J',J);
log('K',K);
log('L',L);
log('M',M);
log('N',N);
log('O',O);
```

```html
This snippet only presents choosen solutions
```

And here are result for small objects on chrome

[image]

Comment: I guess it depends on context, but that's nerdy stuff. No disrespect or denying the effort put into this answer, but for general consumer apps I always find those pedant performance tests out of real life context. Ok, one can save like 5ms here and there. Not a single user will notice this. This could probably make a difference back in 80s-90s when CPU cycle was expensive, but today this is practically irrelevant in 99.9% of the time. Developer's time is much more expensive than the outcome of those micro optimisations especially when UX improvements are negligible or non-existent.

Answer (score 38):

```
for(key in p) {
  alert( p[key] );
}
```

Note: you can do this over arrays, but you'll iterate over the `length` and other properties, too.

Comment: When using a for loop like that, `key` will just take on an index value, so that will just alert 0, 1, 2, etc... You need to access p[key].

Comment: It is the slowest method of array iteration in JavaScript. You can check this on your computer - [Best way to iterate over Arrays in JavaScript](http://jsperf.com/testing-foreach-vs-for-loop/11)

Comment: @Pencroff: the problem is that the question is not about looping through arrays... ;)

Comment: This is something I don't understand on stackoverflow. Richard gave the correct answer, and he was the first one giving that answer, but he did not get any +1? @Bryan `var p = {"p1":"q","p2":"w"};
for(key in p) {
  alert( key );
}` is popping "p1" and "p2" in alerts, so whats wrong about that???

Comment: I think the main difference is the quality: the other answers not only tell how, but also tell the caveats (e.g., the prototype) and how to deal with those caveats. IMHO, those other answers _are_ better than mine :).

Answer (score 37):

Since es2015 is getting more and more popular I am posting this answer which include usage of generator and iterator to smoothly iterate through `[key, value]` pairs. As it is possible in other languages for instance Ruby.

Ok here is a code:

```js
const MyObject = {
  'a': 'Hello',
  'b': 'it\'s',
  'c': 'me',
  'd': 'you',
  'e': 'looking',
  'f': 'for',
  [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
    for (const i of Object.keys(this)) {
      yield [i, this[i]];
    }
  }
};

for (const [k, v] of MyObject) {
  console.log(`Here is key ${k} and here is value ${v}`);
}
```

All information about how can you do an iterator and generator you can find at developer Mozilla page.

Hope It helped someone.

**EDIT:**

ES2017 will include `Object.entries` which will make iterating over `[key, value]` pairs in objects even more easier. It is now known that it will be a part of a standard according to the [ts39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries) stage information.

I think it is time to update my answer to let it became even more fresher than it's now.

```js
const MyObject = {
  'a': 'Hello',
  'b': 'it\'s',
  'c': 'me',
  'd': 'you',
  'e': 'looking',
  'f': 'for',
};

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(MyObject)) {
  console.log(`Here is key ${k} and here is value ${v}`);
}
```

You can find more about usage on
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) page

Comment: This looks totally superfluous/unneeded to me. Would you add it to every object in your system? I thought the point of providing an iterator was so that you could do `for( const [k, v] of myObject )'. It just looks like extra code providing little additional value.

Answer (score 26):

Single line and more readable code can be..

```
Object.entries(myObject).map(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))
```

Comment: good answer and it's more readable than the above solutions but can you explain what happens on the .map(([key, value])  in your answer?

Comment: @Nivethan the output of Object.entries will be an Array of Arrays. 
i.e [ ['key1', 'value'], ['key2', 'value'] ]

So, map will loop over outer array with each array elements passing into its callback function one by one. So, here I have used Array de-structuring syntax ([key, value]) => {} instead of (element) => {}, where element is an array.

Answer (score 23):

After looking through all the answers in here, hasOwnProperty isn't required for my own usage because my json object is clean; there's really no sense in adding any additional javascript processing. This is all I'm using:

```
for (var key in p) {
    console.log(key + ' => ' + p[key]);
    // key is key
    // value is p[key]
}
```

Comment: Whether the JSON object is clean or not is irrelevant. If at any other time some code sets a property on `Object.prototype`, then it will be enumerated by `for..in`. If you are sure you are not using any libraries that do that, then you don't need to call `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: It can be completely clean if created with `Object.create(null)`

Answer (score 21):

via **prototype** with **forEach()** which should skip the **prototype chain** properties:

```
Object.prototype.each = function(f) {
    var obj = this
    Object.keys(obj).forEach( function(key) { 
        f( key , obj[key] ) 
    });
}


//print all keys and values
var obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
obj.each(function(key,value) { console.log(key + " " + value) });
// a 1
// b 2
// c 3
```

Comment: Be careful with the prototype: `obj = { print: 1, each: 2, word: 3 }` produces `TypeError: number is not a function`. Using `forEach` to match the similar `Array` function may reduce the risk somewhat.

Answer (score 19):

It's interesting people in these answers have touched on both `Object.keys()` and `for...of` but never combined them:

```
var map = {well:'hello', there:'!'};
for (let key of Object.keys(map))
    console.log(key + ':' + map[key]);
```

<sub>You can't just `for...of` an `Object` because it's not an iterator, and `for...index` or `.forEach()`ing the `Object.keys()` is ugly/inefficient.

I'm glad most people are refraining from `for...in` (with or without checking `.hasOwnProperty()`) as that's also a bit messy, so other than my answer above, I'm here to say...</sub>

---

**You can make ordinary object associations iterate! Behaving just like `Map`s with direct use of the fancy `for...of`**
[DEMO](http://codepen.io/Hashbrown/pen/mEWadp) working in Chrome and FF (I assume ES6 only)

```
var ordinaryObject = {well:'hello', there:'!'};
for (let pair of ordinaryObject)
    //key:value
    console.log(pair[0] + ':' + pair[1]);

//or
for (let [key, value] of ordinaryObject)
    console.log(key + ':' + value);
```

So long as you include my shim below:

```
//makes all objects iterable just like Maps!!! YAY
//iterates over Object.keys() (which already ignores prototype chain for us)
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
    var keys = Object.keys(this)[Symbol.iterator]();
    var obj = this;
    var output;
    return {next:function() {
        if (!(output = keys.next()).done)
            output.value = [output.value, obj[output.value]];
        return output;
    }};
};
```

Without having to create a real Map object that doesn't have the nice syntactic sugar.

```
var trueMap = new Map([['well', 'hello'], ['there', '!']]);
for (let pair of trueMap)
    console.log(pair[0] + ':' + pair[1]);
```

In fact, with this shim, if you still wanted to take advantage of Map's other functionality (without shimming them all in) but still wanted to use the neat object notation, since objects are now iterable you can now just make a Map from it!

```
//shown in demo
var realMap = new Map({well:'hello', there:'!'});
```

---

**For those who don't like to shim, or mess with `prototype` in general, feel free to make the function on window instead, calling it something like `getObjIterator()` then;**

```
//no prototype manipulation
function getObjIterator(obj) {
    //create a dummy object instead of adding functionality to all objects
    var iterator = new Object();

    //give it what the shim does but as its own local property
    iterator[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj)[Symbol.iterator]();
        var output;

        return {next:function() {
            if (!(output = keys.next()).done)
                output.value = [output.value, obj[output.value]];
            return output;
        }};
    };

    return iterator;
}
```

Now you can just call it as an ordinary function, nothing else is affected

```
var realMap = new Map(getObjIterator({well:'hello', there:'!'}))
```

or

```
for (let pair of getObjIterator(ordinaryObject))
```

[There's no reason why that wouldn't work.](https://jsfiddle.net/4dkos9mw/16/)

Welcome to the future.

Comment: [Case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19110204/2518317) [in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19106881/2518317) [point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21821236/2518317). So long as people scroll down and find it helpful, that's all that matters. Usually it's me trying to do something, not liking the stuff I see online, end up figuring it out, then I come back to share. It's good doco, I've actually come across my own answers before googling things I completely forgot about!

Comment: @HelpMeStackOverflowMyOnlyHope Personally I do not like modifying the prototypes of objects I did not define myself.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen did you even read the whole answer? `For those who don't like to shim, or mess with prototype in general, feel free to make the function on window instead, calling it something like getObjIterator() then;`

Comment: Note that this technique doesn't work on plain objects, but useful nonetheless.

Comment: it does work for plain objects, that's literally the whole point (as well as the variable names like `ordinaryObject` for emphasis that the magic still works for those types). Did you check the demos; what isn't working for you, @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ? (P.S. your SE profile image is boss)

Comment: My fault, I didn't read the part on the shim. It doesn't work for plain objects without modifying the prototype.

Comment: Again, @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ, not true: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4dkos9mw/16/). Take a look at my response to `@Janus`. Hmm, two people have struggled and said this now, so I'll update the answer to make it better, I mightn't have explained how to adapt the technique to not need a prototype manipulation properly

Answer (score 19):

**Using a `for-of` on `Object.keys()`**

Like:

```js
let object = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
};

for (let key of Object.keys(object)) {
  console.log(key + " : " + object[key])
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also use Object.keys() and iterate over the object keys like below to get the value:

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

Object.keys(p).forEach((key)=> {
 console.log(key +' -> '+ p[key]);
});
```

Comment: You saved my time, Thank you

Comment: Happy to know:)

Answer (score 17):

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " = " + p[key]);
    }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Output:<br>
  p1 = values1<br>
  p2 = values2<br>
  p3 = values3
</p>
```

Answer (score 14):

> Object.keys(obj) : Array
>
> retrieves all string-valued keys of all enumerable own (non-inherited) properties.

So it gives the same list of keys as you intend by testing each object key with hasOwnProperty. You don't need that extra test operation than and `Object.keys( obj ).forEach(function( key ){})` is supposed to be faster. Let's prove it:

```js
var uniqid = function(){
   var text = "",
     i = 0,
     possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   for( ; i < 32; i++ ) {
     text += possible.charAt( Math.floor( Math.random() * possible.length ) );
   }
   return text;
  }, 
  CYCLES = 100000,
  obj = {}, 
  p1,
  p2,
  p3,
  key;

// Populate object with random properties
Array.apply( null, Array( CYCLES ) ).forEach(function(){
 obj[ uniqid() ] = new Date()
});

// Approach #1
p1 = performance.now();
Object.keys( obj ).forEach(function( key ){
 var waste = obj[ key ];
});

p2 = performance.now();
console.log( "Object.keys approach took " + (p2 - p1) + " milliseconds.");

// Approach #2
for( key in obj ) {
 if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
  var waste = obj[ key ];
 }
}

p3 = performance.now();
console.log( "for...in/hasOwnProperty approach took " + (p3 - p2) + " milliseconds.");
```

In my Firefox I have following results

- Object.keys approach took 40.21101451665163 milliseconds.
- for...in/hasOwnProperty approach took 98.26163508463651 milliseconds.

PS. on Chrome the difference even bigger http://codepen.io/dsheiko/pen/JdrqXa

PS2: In ES6 (EcmaScript 2015) you can iterate iterable object nicer:

```js
let map = new Map().set('a', 1).set('b', 2);
for (let pair of map) {
    console.log(pair);
}

// OR 
let map = new Map([
    [false, 'no'],
    [true,  'yes'],
]);
map.forEach((value, key) => {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

Comment: if you don't feel like letting go of the {} notation, you can still use `of` [without creating `Map`s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38072602/2518317)

Answer (score 14):

In latest ES script, you can do something like this:

```js
let p = {foo: "bar"};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(p)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Works as a stand-alone, but does not work if this function returns a value for each for condition

Answer (score 13):

Pass your object to `Object.keys()`. This will return an array containing all the keys in the object. You can then loop through the array using `map`. Using `obj[key]` where `obj` is your object and `key` is the current value in the map iteration, you can get the value for that key/property.

```
const obj = { name: "Jane", age: 50 };

Object.keys(obj).map( key => {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Only JavaScript code without dependencies:

```
var p = {"p1": "value1", "p2": "value2", "p3": "value3"};
keys = Object.keys(p);   // ["p1", "p2", "p3"]

for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  console.log(keys[i] + "=" + p[keys[i]]);   // p1=value1, p2=value2, p3=value3
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

Object.keys(p).map((key)=> console.log(key + "->" + p[key]))
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is another method to iterate through an object.

```js
   var p = {
"p1": "value1",
"p2": "value2",
"p3": "value3"
};


Object.keys(p).forEach(key => { console.log(key, p[key]) })
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, however for large objects, the `for` method might be more performant.

Answer (score 10):

Multiple way to iterate object in javascript

Using **for...in** loop

```js
 var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};
for (let key in p){
   if(p.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     console.log(`${key} : ${p[key]}`)
   }
}
```

Using **for...of** loop

```js
 var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};
for (let key of Object.keys(p)){
     console.log(`key: ${key} & value: ${p[key]}`)
}
```

Using [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with **Object.keys**, **Object.values**, **Object.entries**

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};
Object.keys(p).forEach(key=>{
   console.log(`${key} : ${p[key]}`);
});
Object.values(p).forEach(value=>{
   console.log(value);
});
Object.entries(p).forEach(([key,value])=>{
    console.log(`${key}:${value}`)
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Loops can be pretty interesting when using pure JavaScript. It seems that only ECMA6 (New 2015 JavaScript specification) got the loops under control. Unfortunately as I'm writing this, both Browsers and popular Integrated development environment (IDE) are still struggling to support completely the new bells and whistles.

At a glance here is what a JavaScript object loop look like before ECMA6:

```
for (var key in object) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = object[key];
    console.log(key); // This is the key;
    console.log(value); // This is the value;
  }
}
```

Also, I know this is out of scope with this question but in 2011, ECMAScript 5.1 added the `forEach` method for Arrays only which basically created a new improved way to loop through arrays while still leaving non iterable objects with the old verbose and confusing `for` loop. But the odd part is that this new `forEach` method does not support `break` which led to all sorts of other problems.

Basically in 2011, there is not a real solid way to loop in JavaScript other than what many popular libraries (jQuery, Underscore, etc.) decided to re-implement.

As of 2015, we now have a better out of the box way to loop (and break) any object type (including Arrays and Strings). Here is what a loop in JavaScript will eventually look like when the recommendation becomes mainstream:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    console.log(key); // This is the key;
    console.log(value); // This is the value;
}
```

Note that most browsers won't support the code above as of June 18th 2016. Even in Chrome you need to enable this special flag for it to work: `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony`

Until this becomes the new standard, the old method can still be used but there are also alternatives in popular libraries or even [lightweight alternatives](https://github.com/nbouvrette/forEach) for those who aren't using any of these libraries.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle of this working? Here is my attempt. https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/sceeb211/

Comment: @abalter Sorry I realised I had a typo in my code. I fixed it and updated your JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sceeb211/2/

Comment: I'm in chrome and getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object.entries is not a function`. Is it not implemented in chrome yet?

Comment: @abalter It is. Make sure you have Chrome version 51 and that you have enabled the flag as explained in my edit and Jsfiddle comments. You can check the details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Sorry I missed that about the flag. I see it's not a fully implemented feature yet.

Comment: @abalter It's very early to adopt it. I'm not sure what you are trying to do but did you look at alternative solutions such as https://github.com/nbouvrette/forEach

Comment: I just usually use `$.each` or `forEach` along with `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Should mention this is also appropriate if using Babel.

Answer (score 8):

You can add a simple *forEach* function to all objects, so you can automatically loop through any object:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'forEach', {
    value: function (func) {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (!this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // skip loop if the property is from prototype
                continue;
            }
            var value = this[key];
            func(key, value);
        }
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

For those people who don't like the "*for ... in*"-method:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'forEach', {
    value: function (func) {
        var arr = Object.keys(this);
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var key = arr[i];
            func(key, this[key]);
        }
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

Now, you can simple call:

```
p.forEach (function(key, value){
    console.log ("Key: " + key);
    console.log ("Value: " + value);
});
```

If you don't want to get conflicts with other forEach-Methods you can name it with your unique name.

Comment: Modifying the prototypes of built in objects (like `Object`) is generally considered an anti pattern because it can easily cause conflicts with other code. So wound *not* recommend doing it this way.

Answer (score 8):

```
Object.entries(myObject).map(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))
```

You can try like this. `myObject` will be `{name: "", phone: ""}` so and so, this will generate key and value. So key here is `name`, `phone` and value are like `dog`, `123123`.

Example `{name: "dog"}`

Here key is `name` and value is `dog`.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow! As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is not essentially different from the other answers and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers, either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether, this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful not scattered/duplicated.

Answer (score 7):

A good way for looping on an enumerable JavaScript object which could be awesome and common for ReactJS is using `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` with using `map` function. like below:

```
// assume items:

const items = {
  first: { name: 'phone', price: 400 },
  second: { name: 'tv', price: 300 },
  third: { name: 'sofa', price: 250 },
};
```

For looping and show some UI on `ReactJS` act like below:

```
~~~
<div>
  {Object.entries(items).map(([key, ({ name, price })]) => (
    <div key={key}>
     <span>name: {name}</span>
     <span>price: {price}</span>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Actually, I use the destructuring assignment twice, once for getting `key` once for getting `name` and `price`.

Comment: I was exactly looking for this as I'm working with React and how for loops don't work inside `<Fragment>`, this is the perfect solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Dear @Mob_Abominator, thanks for your sweet comment, I'm glad to hear it is useful for you. but I don't understand `how for loops don't work inside <Fragment>`. Does it still remain any problem? if it does please leave a question and tell me, I will answer. if nothing remains and you are ok now. please leave upvote to [this post of me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60470549/6877799). thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would do this rather than checking `obj.hasOwnerProperty` within every `for ... in` loop.

```
var obj = {a : 1};
for(var key in obj){
    //obj.hasOwnProperty(key) is not needed.
    console.log(key);
}
//then check if anybody has messed the native object. Put this code at the end of the page.
for(var key in Object){
    throw new Error("Please don't extend the native object");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In ES6 we have well-known symbols to expose some previously internal methods, you can use it to define how iterators work for this object:

```
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3",
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield *Object.keys(this);
    }
};

[...p] //["p1", "p2", "p3"]
```

this will give the same result as using for...in es6 loop.

```
for(var key in p) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

But its important to know the capabilities you now have using es6!

Comment: A custom object iterator calls the built-in array iterator of an array that generated by `Object.keys()` and allocated in memory... Cool!

Answer (score 6):

```js
    var p =[{"username":"ordermanageadmin","user_id":"2","resource_id":"Magento_Sales::actions"},
{"username":"ordermanageadmin_1","user_id":"3","resource_id":"Magento_Sales::actions"}]
for(var value in p) {
    for (var key in value) {
        if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `json = [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}] for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { for (var key in json[i]) { if (json[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) { console.log(key + " -> " + json[i][key]); } } }`

Answer (score 6):

since ES06 you can get the values of an object as array with

```
let arrValues = Object.values( yourObject) ;
```

it return the an array of the object values and it not extract values from Prototype!!

[MDN DOCS Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

and for keys ( allready answerd before me here )

```
let arrKeys   = Object.keys(yourObject);
```

Comment: The answers asks for a solution that returns both keys and values.

Answer (score 6):

1. Using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [Object hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

   ```js
       var p = {
           "p1": "value1",
           "p2": "value2",
           "p3": "value3"
       };

       for (var key in p) {
           if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
               console.log(key, ' : ', p[key]);
           }
       }
   ```
2. Using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [Object keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

   ```js
       var p = {
         "p1": "value1",
         "p2": "value2",
         "p3": "value3"
       };

       for (var key of Object.keys(p)) {
         console.log(key, " : ", p[key])
       }
   ```
3. Using [Object keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

   ```js
       var p = {
           "p1": "value1",
           "p2": "value2",
           "p3": "value3"
       };

       Object.keys(p).forEach(function(key) {
           console.log(key, ' : ', p[key]);
       });
   ```
4. Using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [Object entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

   ```js
       var p = {
           "p1": "value1",
           "p2": "value2",
           "p3": "value3"
       };

       for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(p)) {
         console.log(key, ' : ', value);
       }
   ```
5. Using [Object entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

   ```js
       var p = {
           "p1": "value1",
           "p2": "value2",
           "p3": "value3"
       };

       Object.entries(p).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, ' : ', value));
   ```

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of options:

1. You can use `for..in` for that

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

for (const item in p) {
  console.log(`key = ${item}, value = ${p[item]}`);
}
```

2. You can also call `Object.entries()` to create an array with all its enumerable properties. after that you can and loop through it using `map`, `foreach` or `for..of`

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};


Object.entries(p).map(item => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};


Object.entries(p).forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
})
```

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};


for (const item of Object.entries(p)) {
  console.log(item)
}
```

More about `Object.entries()`can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to iterate over **[non-enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute)** as well, you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to return an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object.

```js
var obj = Object.create({}, {
  // non-enumerable property
  getFoo: {
    value: function() { return this.foo; },
    enumerable: false
  }
});

obj.foo = 1; // enumerable property

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (name) {
  document.write(name + ': ' + obj[name] + '<br/>');
});
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you for posting this answer. I needed to introspect an `Error` object and couldn't get at the properties in a loop or a `_.forIn(err)` call. Using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err)` allowed me to access all the parts of the `Error` that I couldn't get at before. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If anybody needs to loop through **arrayObjects with condition**:

```js
var arrayObjects = [{"building":"A", "status":"good"},{"building":"B","status":"horrible"}];

for (var i=0; i< arrayObjects.length; i++) {
  console.log(arrayObjects[i]);
  
  for(key in arrayObjects[i]) {      
    
      if (key == "status" && arrayObjects[i][key] == "good") {
        
          console.log(key + "->" + arrayObjects[i][key]);
      }else{
          console.log("nothing found");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Considering ES6 I'd like to add my own spoon of sugar and provide one more approach to iterate over object's properties.

Since plain JS object isn't [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) just out of box, we aren't able to use `for..of` loop for iterating over its content. But no one can stop us **to make it iterable**.

Let's we have `book` object.

```
let book = {
  title: "Amazing book",
  author: "Me",
  pages: 3
}

book[Symbol.iterator] = function(){

  let properties = Object.keys(this); // returns an array with property names
  let counter = 0;
  let isDone = false;

  let next = () => {
    if(counter >= properties.length){
      isDone = true;
    }
    return { done: isDone, value: this[properties[counter++]] }
  }

  return { next };
}
```

Since we've made it we can use it this way:

```
for(let pValue of book){
  console.log(pValue);
}
------------------------
Amazing book
Me
3
```

Or if you know the power of ES6 [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), so you certainly can make the code above much shorter.

```
book[Symbol.iterator] = function *(){

  let properties = Object.keys(this);
  for (let p of properties){
    yield this[p];
  }

}
```

Sure, you can apply such behavior for all objects with making `Object` iterable on `prototype` level.

```
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {...}
```

Also, objects that comply with the iterable protocol can be used with the new ES2015 feature [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator thus we can read object property values as an array.

```
let pValues = [...book];
console.log(pValues);
-------------------------
["Amazing book", "Me", 3]
```

Or you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment:

```
let [title, , pages] = book; // notice that we can just skip unnecessary values
console.log(title);
console.log(pages);
------------------
Amazing book
3
```

You can check out [**JSFiddle**](http://www.es6fiddle.net/isksh68n/) with all code I've provided above.

Comment: I found the code will generate the values but without keys. Is it possible to iterate the values with keys?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just return "yield [key, obj[key]];" from your generator function and then use it like the following "for(let [ key, value ] of {}) { }"

Answer (score 5):

The nearest solution, close to python's enumerate function:

```
for key, value in enumerate(object):
    # Do something
```

is a combo of `Object.entries()` and `for-of` loop:

```
for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    // Do something
}
```

```js
let object = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: "value3",
  key4: "value4",
  key5: "value5"
};

for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(`${key} -> ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Object.entries()` function:

```js
var p = {
     "p1": "value1",
     "p2": "value2",
     "p3": "value3"
 };

for (var i in Object.entries(p)){
 var key = Object.entries(p)[i][0];
 var value = Object.entries(p)[i][1];
 console.log('key['+i+']='+key+' '+'value['+i+']='+value);
}
```

Comment: please don't remove the snippet if you edit my entry

Comment: to increase performance use `var e=Object.entries(p)` and change `Object.entries(p)` to `e` everywhere

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when using Angular, here is the solution that I've found.

**Step 1.** Get all the object keys. using Object.keys. This method returns an array of a given object’s own enumerable properties.

**Step 2.** Create an empty array. This is an where all the properties are going to live, since your new ngFor loop is going to point to this array, we gotta catch them all.
**Step 3.** Iterate throw all keys, and push each one into the array you created.
Here’s how that looks like in code.

```
    // Evil response in a variable. Here are all my vehicles.
let evilResponse = { 
  "car" : 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2013"
    },
   "motorcycle": 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2016"
    },
   "bicycle": 
    { 
       "color" : "red",
       "model" : "2011"
    }
}
// Step 1. Get all the object keys.
let evilResponseProps = Object.keys(evilResponse);
// Step 2. Create an empty array.
let goodResponse = [];
// Step 3. Iterate throw all keys.
for (prop of evilResponseProps) { 
    goodResponse.push(evilResponseProps[prop]);
}
```

Here is a link to the original post. https://medium.com/@papaponmx/looping-over-object-properties-with-ngfor-in-angular-869cd7b2ddcc

Answer (score 2):

This is how to loop through a javascript object and put the data into a table.

```html
<body>
<script>
function createTable(objectArray, fields, fieldTitles) {
  let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  let tbl = document.createElement('table');
  let thead = document.createElement('thead');
  let thr = document.createElement('tr');

  for (p in objectArray[0]){
    let th = document.createElement('th');
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(p));
    thr.appendChild(th);
    
  }
 
  thead.appendChild(thr);
  tbl.appendChild(thead);

  let tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  objectArray.forEach((object) => {
    let n = 0;
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (p in objectArray[0]){
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object[p]));
      tr.appendChild(td);
      n++;
    };
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);    
  });
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  body.appendChild(tbl)
  return tbl;
}

createTable([
              {name: 'Banana', price: '3.04'}, // k[0]
              {name: 'Orange', price: '2.56'},  // k[1]
              {name: 'Apple', price: '1.45'}
           ])
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use my library `monadic-objects` for that. It's designed to simplify object modificatons and make it behave like arrays:

```js
p.forEach((key, value) => console.log(key, value))
```

Installation:
`npm i monadic-objects`

This library also includes methods:

- `map`
- `filter`
- `every`
- `some`

See [README](https://github.com/kerelape/monadic-objects/blob/main/README.md) for more information!

Answer (score 0):

An object becomes an iterator when it implements the .next() method

```js
const james = {
  name: 'James',
  height: `5'10"`,
  weight: 185,

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let properties = []
    for (let key of Object.keys(james)) {
      properties.push(key);
    }

    index = 0;
    return {
      next: () => {
        let key = properties[index];
        let value = this[key];
        let done = index >= properties.length - 1;
        index++;
        return {
          key,
          value,
          done
        };
      }
    };
  }

};


const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next().value); // 'James'
console.log(iterator.next().value); // `5'10`
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 185
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate only over properties use one of the answers above, however if you want to iterate over everything including functions, then you might want to use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```js
for (let o of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)) {
  console.log(o);
}
```

I sometimes use this to fast test all functions on objects with simple inputs and outputs.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted, but looking at this now this is perfect because in javascript "methods" are just properties on an Object in JS `let test = function(){ this.method = () => {}; } console.log(new test());`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

var myMap = new Map( Object.entries(p) );

for ( let [k, v] of myMap.entries() ) {

  console.log( `${k}: ${v}` )
  
}
```

```html
<h3>ECMAScript 2017</h3>
<p><b>Object.entries()</b> makes it simple to convert <b>Object to Map</b>:</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

- single level indent
- single set of brackets
- highest browser compatibility
- hasOwnProperty safe

```js
var p = {"p1": "value1", "p2": "value2", "p3": "value3"};

for (var key in p) if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  var value = p[key];
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Since ES2015 you can use the for of loop, to access the element directly:

```
// before ES2015
for(var key of elements){
  console.log(elements[key]);
}


// ES2015
for(let element of elements){
  console.log(element);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Not just does it not help, it's not accurate. *For...of* only works if *elements* defines an iterator. That's true of Arrays, Sets, and Maps, but not of Objects.

Comment: [you can actually make this work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38072602/2518317), @EvanCarroll

Answer (score -6):

Besause the asker's ['*ultimate goal is to loop through some key value pairs*'] and finally don't looking for a loop.

```
var p ={"p1":"value1","p2":"value2","p3":"value3"};
if('p1' in p){
  var val=p['p1'];
  ...
}
```

Comment: No! He wrote "Now I want to loop through all p elements" so he realy need a loop like in his accepted answer.