# CSS - how to position element to the bottom of its parent container?

Tags: css

In the following example, I am trying to put the child div (the pink rectangle) to lay at the bottom of its parent div. 
I tried to use the suggestion that I found [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom) but it didn't help.
Any idea?

```
<html>
<style type="text/css"> 
    .a {        
        background: gray;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .b {
        background: pink;
        float:  right;                              
        bottom: 0px;
    }   
</style>
<body>
<div class="a">
    the parent
    <div class="b"> child
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand what you mean by "lay at the bottom". Could you give us a more detailed example.

Comment: to be aligned to the bottom. to "stick" to the bottom - that the lower edge of the pink rectangle will be on the same line with the lower edge of the gray rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

make the parent "position: relative" and the child "position: absolute".  Then you can position the child "right: 0; bottom: 0"

```
<html>
<style type="text/css"> 
    .a {             
        position: relative;
        background: gray;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .b {
        background: pink;
        position: absolute;         
        bottom: 0px;       
        right: 0px;
    }   
</style>
<body>
<div class="a">
    the parent
    <div class="b"> child
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Full HTML to show what is discussed in the comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
    .a {        
        background: gray;
        position: relative;
    }
    .b {
        background: pink;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }   
</style>
<body>
<div class="a">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut quam sapien, id dictum purus. Ut vel consectetur justo. Sed suscipit justo ullamcorper diam interdum laoreet pulvinar nisl laoreet. Sed sem est, feugiat commodo bibendum vel, laoreet ac sapien. Fusce nisl nulla, commodo ut ultricies ut, iaculis a dolor. Nunc ultrices elit at tellus scelerisque vel vestibulum justo pretium. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse nec felis sem. Donec at tellus dolor, vehicula placerat lacus. Ut non libero at massa convallis imperdiet non rhoncus tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc nibh velit, congue quis tincidunt sed, feugiat a turpis. Phasellus erat justo, dictum non iaculis sit amet, auctor quis neque. Cras leo tortor, consequat non tincidunt sed, lacinia ut nibh. Etiam eu mollis quam. In eu felis velit, at bibendum sapien. Aenean sed est urna. Sed dignissim dapibus dolor sed pellentesque. Aliquam viverra ipsum sit amet justo gravida in facilisis sapien volutpat.

    <p>Suspendisse commodo vulputate nunc, vitae commodo tellus varius eu. Donec adipiscing diam vel felis blandit lobortis. Donec et turpis nunc. Curabitur ac elementum mi. Aenean libero ipsum, lacinia sit amet ornare sed, sollicitudin quis libero. Vestibulum ullamcorper ullamcorper luctus. Aenean pretium ornare tempor. Sed ultricies eros sem. Aenean placerat tristique tellus nec sodales. Proin sed justo non libero condimentum commodo. Quisque sed nisl nisi, vel mattis nisl. Phasellus rhoncus pharetra egestas. Quisque nec arcu ac neque placerat rutrum. In feugiat justo ac orci dignissim rhoncus. Mauris vitae fringilla magna.

    <p>Nam sagittis erat id sapien lacinia ultrices. Pellentesque ultrices, justo vitae blandit convallis, felis mi laoreet sem, in pharetra libero mauris eget nisl. Etiam in mi eget elit bibendum consectetur et nec nibh. Curabitur in justo arcu. Morbi eget venenatis enim. Duis tempor quam lacinia elit consequat sit amet blandit dolor vulputate. Aenean massa libero, suscipit eu tristique id, imperdiet pellentesque justo. Proin rutrum erat sit amet orci iaculis ut lobortis turpis sagittis. Nam luctus mollis mi, nec laoreet urna semper vitae. Pellentesque in massa enim. Etiam fermentum urna vitae lorem consequat pretium. Maecenas id ligula diam, id consectetur purus. Vestibulum libero velit, tempor hendrerit posuere ut, rutrum nec velit. Suspendisse id pulvinar erat. Sed vulputate, nibh id vulputate vestibulum, dolor elit tincidunt est, sed varius neque tellus tincidunt erat. Nunc volutpat eros in diam semper dictum. Quisque ut ligula felis.

    <p>Ut pharetra feugiat nisi eu viverra. Praesent sollicitudin iaculis elit, ac lobortis ante consectetur sed. Nullam sit amet enim eget massa dapibus molestie. Donec orci diam, tempor sit amet aliquet eget, placerat in nulla. Sed et sollicitudin mi. Donec pulvinar elit pharetra urna ornare sodales. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas et mi libero. Ut et ipsum nec enim adipiscing pellentesque a nec quam. Pellentesque viverra, enim id auctor lacinia, turpis leo blandit odio, et luctus orci purus at nunc. Morbi eu sem id diam aliquam egestas. Vestibulum hendrerit lobortis est a convallis. Nunc quis quam odio, a eleifend dolor.

    <p>Vivamus sollicitudin convallis diam, ut luctus ipsum viverra in. Morbi sit amet sapien urna, sit amet dictum nisi. Duis elit tortor, iaculis nec feugiat in, aliquam ut nisl. Nulla scelerisque sagittis aliquam. Ut tempus auctor tempus. Aliquam auctor vulputate volutpat. Praesent libero orci, volutpat a volutpat ac, vulputate at enim. Phasellus semper sem sed velit bibendum tempus. Aenean ut mauris nisl. Nam sit amet ipsum arcu. Phasellus pretium venenatis egestas. Ut in nulla sem. Proin aliquet facilisis lectus non consequat. Nullam vel magna et ligula viverra sagittis. Fusce in massa in quam vehicula convallis. Nullam placerat erat in nunc eleifend sed dapibus elit tempor.

    <p>Aliquam in erat mi. Suspendisse dui dui, facilisis ac lobortis id, mollis quis enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed in porta arcu. Maecenas aliquam congue sem, at scelerisque odio pharetra ac. In egestas rutrum cursus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam a libero risus. Morbi odio eros, sollicitudin vel mattis vel, aliquet a elit. Suspendisse vel lectus risus, in iaculis ipsum. Etiam vitae justo nibh, non bibendum purus. Quisque mi erat, accumsan sit amet fringilla eu, rhoncus sed ipsum. Ut ac leo a nunc accumsan placerat at ut mauris. Aliquam imperdiet urna urna.

    <div class="b"> child
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote, so I'm up-voting you (for providing a right answer) to restore some karma. Though I'd suggest that explaining your answer might've helped, given the question implies the OP's new to, or inexperienced with, CSS.

Comment: I didn't know CSS have any reasoning behind :)

Comment: Oh, and ´Code´ worth a thousand words

Comment: Yeh, you are right it is working. 
I tried it before (obviously a bit different but when the parent in 'relative' position and the child in 'absolute') and the result was that the pink element was in the bottom of the page out of the its parent's borders.
But again now it work. Case is close (-;

Comment: Sorry - I found out that this answer is not satisfying - making the child element in absoulte position relates it to the window. if I'll remove from the parent's div, than the line: 

'height: 80px;' 
then the children will move to the bottom of the window. If I can't determine the size of the parent DIV, then this solution is no good. This happen to me when I have got a DIV that I don't know his size and want to put in it image and a text that both should be aligned to the bottom- the height of the div will be determined from the height of the image that changes dynamically.

Comment: If you make the parent `relative` and the child `absolute` then the child will be positioned related to the parent, not the window. Try the HTML shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the position attributes (`top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`), the element's `position` CSS attribute must be `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`.

Also, the positions will be calculated relative to the element's offset parent.  In order to make them relative to your `.a` element, it needs to have `position: relative`.

In your case, you need to write

```
.a {  
    background: gray;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
}

.b {
    background: pink;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: And what if I can't make the parent position to be relative. What can be done in this case?

Comment: Why can't you make the parent `position: relative`?

Answer (score 0):

.b needs `position:relative;` absolute would position it according to the window size, not to his parent.

there is also `vertical-align` which gives you a "true" bottom alignment but its only usable with table display properties like table-cell

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using relative/absolute (as mentioned by a bunch of other answers). An alternative (if both the parent and child have known heights) is to set a top margin on the child:

```
.a {        
    background: gray;
    height: 80px;
}

.b {
    background: pink;
    float:  right;       
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;                       
}
```