# CSS height 100% issue

Tags: css, height, footer

I know there are a lot of questions about a css 100% height problem.
However I've tried to follow the instructions there and still the height isn't 100%,
so I thought I'd ask the question again.

The site where you can see the problem is:

[www.exendo.be](http://www.exendo.be)

some css styles:

```
html {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: url("/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 100px #F2F7E8;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
footer-container {
    background: url("/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/exendo-footer_bg.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom #557F40;
    height:146px;
}
```

As you can see on the site, the footer is too high on the page.
If I inspect the page with Firebug, I can see that the html is 100% height, but the body tag isn't. 
The problem both occurs on Firefox and IE.

If anybody could help that would be great!

Answer (score 5):

A number of people suggested position:absolute; bottom:0;

This can cause an issue if the content is taller than the container. The height will not increase so the content will no longer fit and can get cut off or result in ugly scroll bars.

If you can give a fixed height to the container, this is ideal since the height:100% will then work on the child element. In case the content is too large, you can put a background on the child with overflow:visible on the parent, so the content still displays. This helps, but it can still break unless the child is the same width as the parent.

If that doesn't work, I recommend using min-height in em or pixels. This will make sure the height fills the parent, and expands if the content is too long. This worked best for customer comments on [www.baka.ca](https://www.baka.ca)

Answer (score 2):

I think this **[article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom)** can help you.

According to this article:

Assign "position:relative" to your "container" div - page, page-container, or wrapper (I'm not sure to which one of the three, just try), and then "position:absolute; bottom:0;" to your "footer-container" div.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

@denappel; give `html & body 100% height` put `footer` outside of your `main div wrapper` & give margin-bottom in `minus` according to the height of footer.

**css:**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
    background:yellow;
}
.header {
    height: 190px;
    background:green;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:red;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px;
}
```

**check this example**
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/tCdPX/3/

this functionally called [stickyfooter](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I've tried this out (you can check it at exendo.be), but for some strange reason it doens't work.
I've removed the margin:0 auto -142px; because else the footer came even higher. The full height is still not used, and I don't have a clue why...