# img { max-height: 100%; } causes img to exceed bounds

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is this a Chrome bug?

**Here's the HTML**:

```
<div><img src="test.png"></div>
```

**Here's the CSS**:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
div { height: 200px; padding: 75px 0 60px; }
img { max-height: 100%; }
```

**Expected result**: The `img` should have a height of 65px.

**Result in Chrome** (v. 27.0.1453.116) on Mac OS (v. 10.6.8): The `img` has height of 135px and "bleeds" into the parent `div`'s padding. If I change the `padding` of the `div` to `50px 0`, oddly it renders properly.

Play with this in a **codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jhbKz

**Screenshots**:

First block has `padding` of `50px 0`. Second block has `padding` of `75px 0 60px`.

Firefox (correct result)

[image: Firefox]

Chrome (wrong?)

[image: Chrome]

Comment: does the CodeOpen you added show the issue ?
on my chrome didn't see any different with images height or width

Comment: yes, the CodePen shows the issue on my version of Chrome on Mac. The first image renders as expected (height of 100px inside the parent div, which has 50px padding on top and bottom). The second image does not render as expected: it should have a height of 65px, but instead has a height of 135px and bleeds into the parent div's padding bottom.

Comment: What about a CSS `height: 100%;` problem? Why not have a look @ **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534156/css-height-100-issue)** and **[these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSS+height+100%25)**. And yes, in my Chrome in Windows shows the same problem in CodePen. :(

Comment: In case you haven't noticed this yet, the image B height ends up being equal to the `padding-top` + `padding-bottom` of `div.b`.  Very strange...I would go with @Pav's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a container to your Image with width and height of 100%. This will give you the same output on chrome and FF.

```
<div class="b">
    <div style='height:100%;width:100%;'>
        <img src="some image url">
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot explain why this fix works currently, but I myself am trying to reason with it.

Comment: I don't think you need `width: 100%` in this case...otherwise good answer.

Comment: Seems this bug only exists in Chrome. No problems in Safari (v. 5.1.9) or Opera (v. 12.15) either.

Answer (score 0):

Years later, the issue seems to have spread to Firefox.
Pav's workaround did not work for me, maybe because I have "a" not "div". The only way in my case was to display as table:

```
<div style="display: table;">
<a style="height: 100px; display: table-cell;" href="#">
    <img style="max-height: 100%; width: auto;" src="some image url">
</a></div>
```

An additional benefit of "table" is that vertical-align: middle; can be used to center the image (or other content) vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `position: absolute` for your image.

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="img" src="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/1/img-2500.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pavellaptev/ern9Lu3g/11/)