# how can i extend a footer to bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

i have a layout like this

```
<section id="container">
    <header></header>
    <section id="main"></section>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
```

At the moment my page is laid out like this:

```
-------------------
|                 | 100px height
|  HEADER         |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|  MAIN           | 500px height
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|  FOOTER         |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|                 |
-------------------
```

I would like the footer to **extend** following the main content area to the bottom of the page, how can this be achieved?

```
-------------------
|                 | 100px height
|  HEADER         | 
|-----------------|
|                 |
|  MAIN           | 500px height
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|  FOOTER         |
|                 |
|                 |
|  FOOTER         |
-------------------
```

**NOTE:** I have noticed all answers so far will pin the footer to tje bottom of the page, however when dragged the footer simply moves down/the main container expands, *I want the footer to expand.*

Comment: What's the CSS for your footer?

Comment: currently its just width:100%; height:300px; display:block; background:#000;

Comment: I thinkl this answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom

Comment: Change the CSS so the position is absolute and bottom is zero.

Comment: If you use the above example don't forget to pad the bottom of the parent container or the content at the bottom could be masked by the footer.

Comment: depending on your objective and browser compatibility you could simply used position:fixed NOTE(IE 5/6 don’t support position: fixed) but who cares ;)

Comment: see my answer and let me know i am lagging some where...

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, however the answers so far are not *extending* the footer to the bottom of the page, they are simply *fixing* it to the bottom. I asked how to extend. The closest answer is Tim's about setting the body bg etc... but i really would rather not use this method.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I was searching for a solution to this exact problem, and I came across a very simple way of achieving the effect I was going for:

```
footer {
    box-shadow: 0 50vh 0 50vh #000;
}
```

This creates a shadow which will fall off the screen if not needed, but otherwise will give 100vh (a full viewport height's worth) of coverage to the space below the footer, so the body background doesn't appear below it.

Comment: I had a large background image on the body and a partially transparent footer so none of the other answers could have worked.  This worked perfectly!

Comment: Same as @peter - had a background image on body and a broken foot on shorter pages or high resolutions. This was the fix.

Comment: I also had to add `body { height: 100%; }` for this to work, but great solution.

Comment: I used this on a body:after pseudo element and it worked great! Thanks.

Comment: 0px should be "0" and 500px might not be enough. Other than that good solution

Comment: If you're just looking to extend the color all the way down, this is a very elegant, and stupidly simple to implement solution.  Thanks!

Comment: work like a charm! stretch footer color to bottom, simple and elegant. Thanks!

Comment: I can't make up my mind whether I like or hate this solution, but it sure works. I worry about performance. Regardless, it's better to use `50vh` rather than a precise length. Submitted an edit.

Comment: Why is there `50vh` twice instead of one `100vh`?

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

Although this is marked answered, it doesn't seem to fully answer the OPs question.  I had the same challenge and here is what I found to work:

1. Set your HTML & Body to 100% height
2. Ensure all of your content, including your footer is wrapped with a big div (site-container)
3. Fiddle with the space in the footer.

Here is the CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%
}

.site-container{
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
}

.footer{
    padding-bottom: 32000px;
    margin-bottom: -32000px;
 }
```

I found this here: https://www.joestrong.co.uk/blog/2012/01/12/css-tip-extend-your-sites-footer-to-the-bottom-of-the-page/ which contains more info.

Answer (score 6):

I would create the illusion that the footer extends to the bottom if possible.

Say footer background color is #000000;

Set the body background color to #000000

and make sure

spans 100% width.

the color #00000 is for example purposes only you may need an image slice or the lat color used in a gradient etc...

Comment: this, **is** the effect i'm trying to achieve, however its not really extending the footer, which is how i'd like to accomplish it. +1

Comment: If you want your footer to have a dynamic height, this is the way to do it. if it is a fixed height I would use one of the answers above OR use javascript to sniff out ready events and resize events to calc the body height! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/fXf4K/

Comment: this, **is** the effect i'm trying to achieve, however its not really extending the footer, which is how i'd like to accomplish it. +1

Comment: Can you give us an example of what exactly you are trying to do?  What if you just give the footer a fixed height?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sticky footer to achieve that effect, like the one [listed here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/), and apply it to your design to push your footer to the bottom of the document, like in this demo i put up:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/Tydjh/1/show/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/Tydjh/1/).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this to work - so long as the footer is out on its own, i.e. not within a container div or anything.

Basically, I needed my content to be fixed width and centred on a white background with a horizontally repeating background image in the body tag extending the full width of the browser window, providing a nice band beneath the header. I wanted the footer to be in a dark colour and extend to the bottom of the page regardless of the height of the content and browser window size.

My page (very simply) was as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>usual stuff</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>fixed height and containing various stuff</header>
<div id="sidebar">floated left and containing nav</div>
<div id="content">floated left and containing various stuff</div>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
<!-- end container --></div>
<footer>various stuff, address etc.</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in the css include these rules (along with all the other styles):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    footer {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The hidden overflow removed the annoying scrollbar caused by the 100% html and body height compensating for the height of the container and extending beyond the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below fiddle which is demonstrating the concept how to keep the footer at bottom always.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evTb4/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/evTb4/embedded/result/

Comment: thanks, but doesn't really answer the question, I don't want the footer to stick to the bottom, i want it to extend its height.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @c4collins, you can use view height instead of a fixed pixel, in case someone has a huge monitor

```
footer{
  box-shadow: 0 100vh 0 100vh #000000;
}
```

Comment: You should refer to the name of the person whose answer you're referring to because it's not immediately obvious which one you mean.