# HTML: I want to position this paragraph text to bottom of my page?

Tags: css, html, paragraph

*hi*,

**Currently the text is at the top of my website but i want it bottom;**

```
 <p style="text-align:relative;">this is best day ever!this is best day ever!this is best day ever!<p>
```

when i edit it and add text-align:bottom it dosent works!!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this code :

```html
  <html>
        <head>
            <title>test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="position: relative">
                <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center"> TEXT YOU WANT
                </p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <p id="Bottom">this is best day ever!this is best day ever!this is best day ever!<p>
```

and CSS :

```
#Bottom {
   position : absolute;
   bottom : 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VJain/WUV2t/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
style="position:absolute; bottom:0px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position the element and set its bottom property to 0.

```
p{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/zMKbf/

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
    height:200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This is a better way...

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="display: table;">
                <p style="display: table-row;vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center"> TEXT YOU WANT
                </p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

i found it in this question, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/how-can-i-position-my-div-at-the-bottom-of-its-container/19110204#19110204`
in `Hashbrown` answer