# Have <a> link fill div vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an `<a href >` link fill the vertical height on a div that is set up in table-cell display.

The height might vary so setting padding is not an option (this might be my fall-back but will restrict the final solution). 
I want it to do the equivalent of `height:100%` but that does not work as can be seen in this example: 
 http://jsfiddle.net/VmcXh/1/

The result I want is for the link to fill the 'cell', both so that the background color can change as a visual cue and so the user can click anywhere in the space.
In the example I have used `background-color` to show the links, in the real site this is an image.

Is this possible?

Update:

It seems the answer is No, at least not reliably across browsers.
I've accepted the closest answer to this which also contains a link to an SO question that describes the relevant ambiguity in the spec.

Comment: display:block on the anchor, or put the div inside the anchor

Comment: `display:inline-block` ? http://jsfiddle.net/VmcXh/3/

Comment: For `display: inline-block` solution also add `vertical-align: top`: http://jsfiddle.net/3MmLz/.

Comment: @Banana I already had `display:block` on the anchor, switching the order also does not do it

Comment: @JackPattishallJr., DRD,  Sorry, neither of these solutions are working in Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `height:0px` to the parent elemetns `#calla` and `#calsd` so that the `height:100%` on anchors will work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmcXh/4/)

(*Parent element needs explicit height set for `%` height. refer this [old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684509/how-do-i-make-a-div-fill-an-entire-table-cell)*)

*Update:*

You can also apply `display:inline-block;` to the anchors as [Jack Pattishall Jr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253479/jack-pattishall-jr) pointed out in the comments

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmcXh/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this isn't working, either on my site or the JSFiddle demo, so maybe it is browser dependent? I am using latest version of Firefox

Comment: Hmm, yes, I can see this working in both IE and Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox.  Unusual for FF to be the one to let the side down, but unfortunately I therefore don't think I can use it as an anwer

Comment: @AntG It's working in chrome, safari & opera (*webkits*), updated solution is working in chrome, safari, opera & ie. Nothing works in FF!. Please check the accepted answer for the question i mentioned in answer... since the spec doesn't clearly mention how to implement it, it seems different engine are using their own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

provide some javascript function on div and apply style `cursor:pointer`

here is  my

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmcXh/5/)