# How to make divs to fill all width and be in one line like TDs in TR?

Tags: html, css, width

I am trying to imitate table rows and cells with use of divs.
I want same results as:

```
<table width = '100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>asd</td>
        <td>dsa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And trying in that way:

```
<div style = 'width: 100%; border: dashed;'>
    <div style = 'width: 50%; display: table-cell; border: dashed;'>asd</div>
    <div style = 'width: 50%; display: table-cell; border: dashed;'>dsa</div>
</div>
```

And that:

```
<div style = 'width: 100%; border: dashed;'>
    <div style = 'width: 50%; display: inline; border: dashed;'>asd</div>
    <div style = 'width: 50%; display: inline; border: dashed;'>dsa</div>
</div>
```

And when inner div's width is 100%.

But inner divs never fill whole width of parent div.
The best case - they are one after another, but **"minimal to fit content width"**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: table;` to the parent div.

```
<div style = 'width: 100%; border: dashed; display: table;'>
    <div style = 'width: 50%; display: table-cell; border: dashed;'>asd</div>
    <div style = 'width: 50%; display: table-cell; border: dashed;'>dsa</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgemxvu7/

Comment: will this apply all table bugs? I means wrong height calculations

Comment: @Kosmos How do you define table bugs? Tables are not buggy, if you use them correct. And to me this seems a correct use case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119868/why-my-heights-fixer-code-work-wrong-when-browser-window-restored-after-being-ma - Here table height calculations bugs.

Comment: @Kosmos I'm not sure if there will be such bugs. If you want to use the table for layout, you should instead really consider using Bootstrap.

Comment: Will test that for bugs and see how is that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: table` to the div containing the table rows/cells, and then just remove the `width: 50%` stuff.

```
<div class="table" style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell">
            Data1
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell">
            Data2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle to see how I did it with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/Chartax/3mysLndy/

But looking at your other questions, it appears that you want to use tables for layouts as opposed to divs. Just changing the tag to div and making them all act identically to tables is not really the way to go.

Use divs with dynamic sizing (width: 20% etc.) so that you are reacting to the user's browser and screen size.

Comment: sometimes nothing is more easy than tables.

Comment: Clinging to tables to layout content is like not using a car because nothing is more easy than riding a horse. If you want to use tables, use tables. There is no point in using divs and making them act exactly like tables