# How to vertically stretch span to its parent element <td> with css in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a table that contains span elements. I need these span elements to be stretch to the full width and height of the table cell  that the span element is in.

I can easily stretch the span horizontally to 100% but I am not having as much luck stretching the span vertically. I've already spent a few hours trying different combinations of the following css properties and their various values..."display", "overflow" and "position" and others. So far no luck.

Any tips how to stretch the spans to the 100% height of the parent element  would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code sample:

```css
.testTable tbody>tr>td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.customSpan {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 width=500px class="testTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head123</th>
      <th>head123</th>
      <th>head123</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="customSpan">test 123</span></td>
      <td><span class="customSpan">test 123</span></td>
      <td><span class="customSpan">test 123 test 123</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="customSpan">test 123 test 123 test 123 test </span></td>
      <td><span class="customSpan">test 123 test 123 test 123 test January test 123 test 123 test 123 test 123 test 123 test</span></td>
      <td rowspan="2"><span class="customSpan">test 123/span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><span class="customSpan">test 123</span></td>
      <td><span class="customSpan">test 123 test 123 test 123</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's a visual representation of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to color the background of the td you can just put the class directly on the td? You will not have to worry about styling the span. What i the span used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a height value to the td, like this:

```
.testTable td{
  height:100%;
}
```

There's an interesting post about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19703263/7920525

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, as it is often the case, this solution works in Chrome and FF but doesn't appear to work in Edge (v40) or IE11. My primary browsers of concerns are IE and Edge.

Comment: If you add a specific height value does that work? like `height: 100px;`. It looks to work for me on Edge with that specified.

Comment: ha! yes, it seems to work ... .testTable tbody >tr >td{    vertical-align: top; height: 1px; } even if I set the height to only 1px. I am puzzled but I seems to do the trick. Thank you very much, @webbm!