# Angular custom mat-cell component is not completly filling the cells background-color and also moves the content upwards

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I´m pretty new to Angular and typescript and my target is to create a checkbox inside a mat-cell that based on the `childIsChecked` state of the checkbox, changes the background-color of the cell.

I created a `<custom-mat-cell>` that is going to change the background color based on a `<custom-checkbox>`(normal checkbox with ability to output the checked state). The color change works perfectly fine. But the background-color seems to not completly fill the actual cell itself and when the checkbox is clicked for the first time, the content is also going to move upwards.

**So basicaly my questions are:**

How can i fully fill the background-color of the actual cell? And how can i prevent the content from moving around?

I have already tried giving the row a height in px and then setting the `height` and `width` to a 100% for the cell which seems to be the solution for non-Angular tables as mentioned here:

1. [Make a DIV fill an entire table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215553/make-a-div-fill-an-entire-table-cell)
2. [How do I make a div fill an entire table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684509/how-do-i-make-a-div-fill-an-entire-table-cell)

**My attempt**

custom_mat_cell.components.css

```
.checked {
  background-color: green;
}

.unchecked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

custom_mat_cell.components.html

```
<mat-cell  [ngClass]="{'checked':childIsChecked, 'unchecked':!childIsChecked}">
  <custom_checkbox (changeBackground)="change_parent_background()"></custom_checkbox>
</mat-cell>
```

custom_mat_cell.components.ts

```
export class custom_mat_cell {
  childIsChecked: boolean = false

  constructor() {
  }

  change_parent_background(){
    this.childIsChecked =!this.childIsChecked
  }
}
```

cell/column generating code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(page_count); let i = index">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{i+1}}">
        <mat-header-cell class="page_cell" *matHeaderCellDef>Page {{i + 1}}</mat-header-cell>
        <custom_mat_cell *matCellDef="let element, let j = index"></custom_mat_cell>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

My attempt so far leads to this:

[image: I would like to somehow fill the full range of the cell]

I would like to somehow fill the full range of the cell

[image: When i click onto the checkbox, the content is moving upwards]

When i click onto the checkbox, the content is moving upwards.

Comment: Please share a working stackblitz with the issue replicated and screenshots on how the output should be!

Comment: One thing I would take a look at it is verifying that when you check the checkbox that it doesn't apply some sort of other CSS styling based on the checked state.

Comment: @SomeStudent ty that one helped me a lot. Its actually adding some column based css classes which makes them move when they are applied. Its adding `mat-cell cdk-column-columnname mat-column-columnname` to them.

Comment: You can try to override those styles as needed in your css, may need to use !important. I can't recall off the top of my head, but I want to say material makes heavy usage of flex layouts and the like (which makes sense, since flex layouts make life easy)