# Footer will not position itself at the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this footer that will not stick to the bottom of the page.

I think the issue is with my `HTML` and `body` not spanning the entire site but I just cannot find the exact place to correct this. I know its a big no-no to link to my page but I simply don't know what code to post here.

I cannot set the content to `static` instead of `absolute` because then my menu items will start pushing the content divs around when they open.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom?rq=1

Comment: There are *many* great examples in the answer above. One of them should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because of your `#content`. You just try to change its position as following:

```
#content{
    position : static;
}
```

Or you just simply remove it because the position is set as `static` by default.

Comment: It is true that it solves the footer problem but then the menu will start pushing my content div arround :(

Comment: @AronChan Can you update your question by putting how your menu pushing the content div? I tried on your website and It has nothing strange.

Comment: try and take a look now. ill set content to static so it will reproduce the issue

Comment: if you hover the menu items now they will push the rest of the design

Comment: The submenu elements need to be positioned absolutely.

Comment: ok that seems to solve the issue. there is still a few issues with the way it displays the submenu but if i can fix it i will select your anwser. thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To fixed position into bottom you can try this code

Html:

```
<div class="tofix">
  <p>Fixed this div into bottom</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.tofix{
      width:300px;
      position:fixed;
      bottom:0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position:absolute` from your #content.

Also It worked when I first opened the link, please don't change the live code while asking the question.

Comment: And make the on hover sub menu `position:absolute` and position it with `top` and `left` etc.

Comment: or you can put `position: absolute` on the submenuts and then `position: relative` on their parents so that the `top` and `left` properties are just relative to the submenus' parent element.

Comment: the problem is that the submenus open on several menu items. so giving them specific top and left properties will not work

Comment: @AronChan, true, to make it work for all menu options use @Arnelle's suggestion of adding `position:relaitve;` to the parent menu items, then the top  and left attributes are relative to menu item which is it's parent.