# Unable to bottom the text like float:bottom

Tags: css

I followed the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526041/586051) but, the text doesn't float at the bottom in  [my webpage](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/9u45Q/35/show), .

Right now, my CSS looks like this:

```
#note{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How do I get it at the bottom, like a footer or copyright message? Also, why is it not centring?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/9u45Q/35/)

Comment: Change position:absolute to position:relative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
html{
   height:100%;
}
```

To your CSS to ensure `body` extends to the height of the viewport.

To center, add `width:100%` to `#note`

Comment: Now the other `div` is getting full height for some reason. http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/9u45Q/38/show/

Comment: Because you have height 100% on #movies_booked, remove this and it looks OK

Answer (score 0):

Your note is sitting at the bottom of the container, so that part is working. Your container maybe isn't as tall as you'd like it to be? Also you can center it by setting the width of the #note to 100%. It's currently centered but because it's an absolutely positioned it's width is not the same as it's parent.