# Make footer to be at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have found a lot of similar questions on SOF  but unfortunately they all relate to : how to make a sticky footer. I'm not trying to make my footer appear at the bottom of the page at any time (I mean : no matter where the user is in the page).

Actually what I'm trying to achieve is very simple but I couldn't find a solution. I have many pages that do not have a lot of text, so currently the footer is something like one line after the end of the text and there is a big blank at the bottom of the page. I would like that the footer be at the bottom of the page if there is only a few text of the page.

I have to put this on my footer class :

```
height : 100%
```

and then this

```
margin-top: 100%
```

And some other stuff, but it didn't make it.

Thank you !

Comment: possible dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom/9090522#9090522

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking if it relates to the same problem

Comment: Yes, the answers provided therin indeed solved my problem, thank you @13ruce1337 . I used the solution provided by Hashbrown (The concept is to use css properties to make the main content present like a table and the footer present like a row-table and then set the vertical positioning of the footer to 'bottom'.

Comment: There are so many questions about sticky footers that I missed this one. Thank you everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your footer to always be at the bottom of the page,  then you will have to specify a value for height for the 'content' section of your page. This will force your footer to always be at the bottom. Try something like this:

```
height: 800px
```

for the div that represents your content.

OR

**Use Absolute positioning**

Apply this to your footer.

```
.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/892JK/

Just observe that its the above two properties namely position: absolute and bottom:0px that make it always 'stick' to the bottom of the page.

This is quite similar to **'sticky' header** concept where the concept is, errm, looked at the opposite way i.e. the properties would be modified as these for sticky header

```
.stickyHeader {
   position:fixed;
   top: 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: The problem with your solution is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom/9090522#9090522

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr I know that. Which is why I gave two solutions AND differentiated them with the word OR.

Comment: Unfortunately, first one is far from a valid solution.  check http://jsfiddle.net/892JK/1/ to see that it doesn't work for varying screen sizes.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Your fiddle is wrong. It doesn't implement my solution if that was your idea to begin with. Let me create a fiddle to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thank you, I actually used the answer provided here stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/… (Answer of Hashbrown) but I first tried your answer and it was working as expected. The only problem is that it is additing extra-blank at the end of the page unless the min-height provided exactly match the height of the user screen. That's why Hashbrown answer is the best way to go !

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Try this http://jsfiddle.net/b4CG6/ Just play with this by increasing the height and you'll observe that the footer will always stay at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That just adds color to the divs.  My point was you can never guarantee that the screen height will be `800 px;` for all users.  For smaller screens,  there will be an unnecessary scroll.  What if the content was bigger than `800 px;`,  see this [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4CG6/1/) from your reference for example.

Comment: Anyway,  we can leave the discussion by agreeing to disagree with each other.  I just couldn't accept that this CSS can be used on any page with different quantities of content.  No offense.  Cheers!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Hmm, so you have decided to crucify me for 800px. Just kidding!!! I only gave 800px as an arbitrary value. I did not mean it to be taken literally. If you read my answer above I said "Try something like this". My intention was to give him the idea not the code :)

Comment: I agree.  I just meant that `n px;` will not work for all pages. :)

Comment: No offense taken, mate!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use min-height property in style-sheet for a particular div in which you have place content, just before footer.

```
<div class="textclass">
 <p> 
 Text or content
 ..........
 </p>
</div>

<footer>
............
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.text-class{
min-height:700px; /*adjust height at your end */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually used the answer provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom/9090522#9090522 (Answer of Hashbrown) but I first tried your answer and it was working as expected. The only problem is that it is additing extra-blank at the end of the page unless the min-height provided exactly match the height of the user screen. That's why Hashbrown answer is the best way to go !

Answer (score 1):

I have used this method: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's       height */
}
.footer, .push {
  height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify a fixed height of the main div containing the body elements and then specify the footer.it will always show after the specified height.