# Toggle collapse text to single line

Tags: html, css, expand

I'm want to collapse a long text to a single line and show a `MORE` link on the right. The expanded text should show a `LESS` link on the bottom and also on the right. Some examples could make it clear:

```
text text text MORE

text text text text
text           LESS
```

The collapsed state seems to work fine with `position: relative; float: right`, but I don't know how to achieve the expanded state. There's nothing like `float: right-bottom` (actually even simulating `float: bottom` needs a [complicated hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom), but this hack doesn't seem to be usable in my case). The algorithm is trivial: *If there's enough space after the text, put it at the end of the last line, otherwise, put it in a next line (also right-aligned)*, but how to tell the browser?

More examples, how it should work.

```
text           MORE

text a_long_word
text text text LESS

text a_long_word
an_even_longer_word
               LESS
```

*Note that the line `text           MORE` should be produced as a shortened version of the lines below.*

I sort of got it working with something like

```
<div><a>MORE</a><span>the text....</span><a>LESS</a></div>
```

hiding one of the links, and setting `overflow: hidden; height: 20px;` in the collapsed case. Now, I'd like to get `text-overflow: ellipsis`, too...

I'm not looking for a pure CSS solution. I know the height of the expanded text and if I also knew where it ends horizontally, I'd position `MORE` absolutely and call it a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems really simple with CSS, unless I'm missing something. What about this? http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/AwfoI

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

div {width: 20%; margin: 30px; background: #f7f7f7; overflow: hidden;}
b {float: right;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <span>text</span> <b>MORE</b>
</div>

<div>
    <span>text a_long_word text text text</span> <b>LESS</b>
</div>

<div>
    <span>text a_long_word an_even_longer_word</span> <b>LESS</b>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see I was doing something wrong.... but what you're missing: The text in your first `div` should be as long as the second or third one, but constrained to a single line by the style.