# how to stick buttons on the same height bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing this [site](http://www.cineteatromatao.com.br/index3.php#), and i got stuck in a problem.

on the "Lançamentos" section i have to always keep the "trailer" and "sinopse" links on the same height, but i can't since the bootstrap columns dont have equal height

[bootply here by JordanD](http://www.bootply.com/zEVFwK4515)

can anybody help me please?

Comment: Putting your code in bootply i don't see problems, edit this to recreate your problems then update your question with it please: http://www.bootply.com/zEVFwK4515

Comment: what i want is to have the trailer and sinopse links on the same line, in the bootply you can see the problem

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is by splitting your content into rows. Designate one row for the poster/title, and a separate row for the Trailer/Synopsis links. As long as the columns within each row match up (and the container is fluid) it will all match up.

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/2jz49daGa1

You could also break it up into a table (pretty similar approach actually).

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/7dxa8ndiac

Now, if you still want it to be responsive design, I would FIX the height of the entire column AND the height of the title. This way, you can add as many movies as you want and it'll appropriately put them side-by-side. If you want their widths to remain static as well, change the container-fluid to container.

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/GcuLvlmdOI#

Without fixing heights, you can use a [flex](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout to achieve the desired result. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom) post to see how to position an element relative to the bottom.

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/PSE8nAvaL3

Comment: see my edit, that might be more what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for your help, we are almost there, the site has to be responsive, but the title and the height of the columns cannot stay fixed because the title height will change according to the number of its chars, therefore, the column height changes as well

Comment: are you trying to achieve this without javascript/jquery?

Comment: i dont have the knowledge necessary to do this with jquery or pure javascript, maybe if you help me.. thanks again!!

Comment: Is this more what you're looking for? (pure CSS/html) http://www.bootply.com/PSE8nAvaL3

Comment: thats exactly what i'm looking for buddy! is this solution cross-browser?

Comment: i'm trying flex box, now height is ok now, but the width bugs when i resize, try it [here] (http://www.cineteatromatao.com.br/index3.php)

Comment: no problem ;D but what's the bug you're referring to? What browser are you using? When I resize the window (using Chrome) it seems to behave well.

Comment: hmmm you might want to experiment with the flex layout link I gave you. I'll take another look at it this weekend for you

Comment: i came with a solution using javascript, if you want to check it here's the [link] (http://www.cineteatromatao.com.br/index3.php)