# Making a div float to the bottom of a static nav element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap based code:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="collapse sidebar-collapse">
    <nav id="sidebar">
       <ul id="main-nav" class="open-active">
           ....
       </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for #sidebar:

```
#sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  position: static;
}
```

This creates a nice sidebar that stretches from top to bottom. However, I can't seem to figure out how to add a div that rests at the very bottom of the sidebar.

A screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Here is the code for that `Test Div` in the screenshot:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
    Test Div
</div>
```

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom/27812717#27812717

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sidebar fills up 100% of the page's height, you can create a wrapper that is `absolute` positioned in the sidebar with the `bottom` property set to `0px`.

This should look something like this:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And it's [straight from this example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp). As another commenter already pointed out, you might have to change the `static` positioning of the parent `#sidebar` element.

To my knowledge this would be the only non-Javascript approach, but it will only work if the sidebar is at 100%.

**Notable alternative option using JavaScript:**

Let's say you know the heights of all the elements you are working with. You could then simply adjust the `margin-top` property of `div` element to be placed at the bottom.

This would look something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var header = document.getElementById("heading");
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
    var height = document.body.scrollHeight;

    bottom.style.marginTop = (height - header.clientHeight) + 'px';

}
```

I hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Now that I think about this more, this is a perfect use case for the [`calc()` CSS3 function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). You might want to check it out.

Using this has a few caveats, like if you don't know the height of the content in the bottom-positioned `div` 100% of the time or if you care about cross-compatibitly problems ([although I would say it has pretty good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)).

This code would look something like this:

```
.bottom {
    /* should be moved down a distance equal to the height of
       parent container minus the height of the bottom div
       and the div above it */
    margin-top: calc(100% - (20px + 40px));
}
```

Check out [these neat use cases](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) to see if this is an option you would want to consider exploring further.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your div within the sidebar, and for your CSS put:

```
    .div {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
     }
```

Comment: Already tried that. I added a screenshot of what I am trying to do. The "Test Div" I have injected that you see in that shot is using this same CSS.

Comment: Change your sidebar from "position: static;" to "position: relative;" It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change #sidebar to position:relative? That should make the absolute positioning work.