# Is there a CSS equivalent to float: down

Tags: css, css-float

I was wondering if there is some sort of CSS equivalent to:

```
float: down;
```

or some way make a element or div go to the bottom of the page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27812717/2680216

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set it that way:

```
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
```

I suppose you'll like this as well with it additionally:

```
z-index: 9999;
```

All above together will make the element stick to the bottom even when you scroll the page.

Answer (score 6):

Using flexboxes, you could set the child element to [`align-self: flex-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rh4Lc5dr/)

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
}
.child {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```css
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    display: flex;
}
.child {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f00;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Align to the bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you would have to use `absolute`/`fixed` positioning.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wawhc3ud/)

```
.align-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

In some cases, you would also have to relatively position the parent element so that the absolute positioning is *relative* to it.

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.align-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="align-bottom">Align to the bottom</div>
```