# Html & Css - Changing the Gravity

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm building a website where the elements are really only at the bottom. 
I want my vertical starting place to start at the bottom instead of the top, and I want to do this without taking those elements out of the normal flow of the page (So no absolute positioning) so that the position of one element can depend on the position of the other.
How do I do this?
Here's a visual explanation of the 'elements at the bottom' thing.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrPtt.jpg

```
    <head>
    <style>
        body {
            background: url('Index-Background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        section {
            margin-left: 2%;
        }
        nav {
            margin-bottom: 6.66%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <h1>The Great Composers</h1>
            <div>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a pie\sum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</div>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#0">Gershwin</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Debussy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "I'm building a website where the elements are really only at the bottom."?

Comment: http://imgur.com/YrzkQfi

Comment: He just wants his website to follow gravity. What he means by that is that the elements should align automatically from bottom to top instead of the normal behaviour which is top to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some workarounds. You can do something like this,

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table;
}
main {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

See the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/L1w9m3mz/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `section` and `nav` orders

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#0">Gershwin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Debussy</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section>
    <h1>The Great Composers</h1>
    <div>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a pie\sum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
html, body {
      position: relative; 
     ...
   }
html {
     position: relative;  
     ...
   }
```

Edit: This might help.
[How can I position my div at the bottom of its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom?rq=1)

Comment: But how would that make them be at the bottom?

Comment: What is "them" here?

Comment: @Oli, please check the edited answer above and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, i'm still not entirely sure what you want to achieve, however if you are trying to make the nav bar horizontal. You'll need to add the following css:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `position:fixed` to set the `nav` positioning. Here are the what i conclude from the image you attached : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ar1aw9uL/)

Answer (score 0):

use flexbox - all modern browsers support 
add .reverse where you want to reverse.

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

```
.reverse {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
```