# Why position: absolute; and bottom: 0; not being at body's bottom?

Tags: html, css

update: I know adding a position: relative; to body will make the element be at body's bottom, I just didn't find the description of when not found the non-static parent, what the position would be related to. So I don't think this question is duplicated to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/how-can-i-position-my-div-at-the-bottom-of-its-container). Thanks to @Ben Kolya Mansley

====

I am writing a component, and met a problem. I set an element position absolute and bottom 0, and append it to document.body (the body height is more than a screen's height), but it is not at body's bottom but viewport's bottom. Why is it so wired?

I read the mdn of position and bottom. It says element with position absolute will look for a non-static positioned parent, if not found, it will be relative to body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        height: 1500px;
      }
      .bar {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="bar">this is bar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should really place your `<style>` tags inside the `<head>` element - not your `<body>`

Comment: Because the body needs `position:relative` as the default is `position:static`. The `body` doesn't count as a parent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) on absolute positioning:

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, it is positioned relative to the ICB (initial containing block), which the containing block of the document's root element.

This describes that it's not the `body` that it is positioned to, but the *initial containing block*,  which has the dimensions of the viewport, not the body.

By adding `position: relative;` to `body`, the element will be aligned to the bottom.

More info on the Initial Containing Block can be found at the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)