# How can I float a div element to the bottom of the screen with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website with different sections, one at the bottom of the screen. I first tried putting the div element inside of a footer element. This didn’t work. The div was still at the top of the screen. I was out of ideas, so I searched for a solution on Google. Nothing I tried worked. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you try to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows your issue? This might just be a snippet of the code you already have. It's difficult to suggest what you should do without seeing specifically what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I position my div at the bottom of its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/how-can-i-position-my-div-at-the-bottom-of-its-container)

Comment: @lawrence-witt: It is "Stack Overflow" (not "StackOverflow"). See e.g. *"*[Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)"* (the last section - scroll down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to always be at the bottom of the screen (IE: touching bottom of monitor) you can use

```
.myElementClass{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Just make sure that it's not inside anything declared with `position: relative` or it will be stuck at the bottom of that element.

If you want it to be at the bottom of the wrapper element, use

```
.myWrapperClass{
    position: absolute;
}
```

and put the `.myElementClass` element inside the `.myWrapperClass` element

Answer (score 1):

If you need your footer to be seen always on the screen or like this at the end of the page, here is the answer. The explanation is same as [zachThePerson's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670843/how-can-i-float-a-div-element-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen-with-css/64671326#64671326).

```css
.main {
    position: relative;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <h1>The float Property</h1>
      <p>In this example, the image will float to the right in the text.</p>

      <div class="box">
         <div class="box1"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout), and the below solution could be useful.

You can put the main content of your page in the div with class `main-content`, and with the Flexbox settings below, the footer will always be pushed to the bottom.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="main-content">Just a random div with some content</div>
    <div class="footer">Div to be on the bottom of the page</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

The above code won't change the height of the `flexbox-container` div, though. So you may want to add something like this:

```
.flexbox-container {
  ...
  height: 100vh;
}
```

A good page with explanation for the Flexbox being used is *[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)*.