# background repeat but only have it on the bottom half

Tags: html, css

consider the situation below:

```css
section {
  height: 1200px;
  background: url('https://pngimg.com/uploads/sun/sun_PNG13449.png'), blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc
</section>
```

I want to have it only on the bottom section, not the entire section. I dont think background position will work because it's `repeat` default.

Upon posting these are the "similar" questions:

[How to align content of a div to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom)

this isn't related to bg images
and neither are these

[Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

[How can I position my div at the bottom of its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/how-can-i-position-my-div-at-the-bottom-of-its-container)

and then

[Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

but its not relevant either.

is it possible to do a background repeat on a particular section within an element or does it need it's own div?

Answer (score 1):

`repeat-x` and place it at bottom

```css
section {
  height: 1200px;
  background: 
    url('https://pngimg.com/uploads/sun/sun_PNG13449.png') bottom repeat-x
    blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc  content etc
</section>
```