# Float a span bottom right inside a div

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a div to float to the bottom of its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311990/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-float-to-the-bottom-of-its-container)

I have this code to float a div to the bottom right side of a div.  But the span gets stuck to the upper left.

```
<div id="color_tile" class="select_tile" title="Choose color" style="background: grey; background-image: url(wallpaper/201_color_picker.jpg);" >    
  <span id="color_picker" style="visibility: visible; display: block; float: right; vertical-align: bottom;"></span>
</div>
```

Is there a different way to place the span?

Comment: Give the div a relative position and the span an absolute position with bottom and right set to zero.

Comment: Clarify your question in that you want to keep the span in flow with the rest of the items. Only sane solution I can come up with is what you already have (minus vertical align, that doesn't make sense) so you're probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: See also: [wrap text around a bottom right div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div).

Answer (score 8):

You should probably separate your HTML/CSS from each other properly.

Your code could look something like this

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>Absolute right bottom aligned to div...</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { position: relative; }
div > span { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Obviously your div should have some height/width which exceeds that of the span, but generally this is a very acceptable way of doing it.

This doesn't make the content of the div 'flow' around the span but that wasn't specified clearly. As said, what you have there should work in that case and if it doesn't it is in the rest of your code.

Comment: You should definitely separate your CSS from your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

vartical-align is very particular to get to work (which is why I almost never use it)

On the span:
`position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;`

and put a height/width on the parent div and you'll be all set

Comment: -1 Absolutely positioning the element is not going to allow it to "float" (cause contents to wrap around it).

Comment: If you read the question the is no other content in the div. There is also two different requests `float a div to the bottom right side` and `Is there a different way to place the span` this is solving the latter which is the actual question. I assumed the `float` term came from `float:right` and was not the proper terminology in the first place onto what he/she wanted to accomplish

Comment: You don't downvote answers which are the result of poor question quality. +1

Comment: @sg3s No, I downvote answers which do not, in my (personal, limited, fallible, and perhaps incorrect) opinion actually answer the question. I also downvote questions which have poor quality. :) If the OP comes back and clarifies that no "floating" was desired, I'll certainly change to a +1

Comment: @Phrogz and I guess I shouldn't upvote without reading the actual answer :s This solution is incomplete, the wrapping div should at least be positioned for this to work correctly.

Comment: @Phrogz So your saying my answer is poor but you close this one on the basis of exact duplicate of a question whos top answer is the same as mine...? That doesn't make much sense