# Positioning a div at the bottom of a fixed size container

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble finding a way to position a div at the bottom of the container.

What I tried:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:10px;
```

But it displays the div I need at the bottom, outside the container in which I need it in...

I appreciate any help in this regard.

Heres the jsfiddle showing the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gd6JC/

Comment: This question has been asked dozens of times - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311990/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-float-to-the-bottom-of-its-container?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the container to `position: relative` and make sure that the `<div>` you are trying to position at the bottom of the container is nested inside the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/RdjS3/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the rule `position: relative` to the containing div.

http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/Gd6JC/1/