# bootstrap column chart

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way that I can turn bootstrap progress bars sideways to use them as a column chart?
I'm thinking about going to Google graphs, but it's easier to work with bootstrap.
Here's some code to get past the StackOverflow quality standards.

```
Code goes here.
```

Comment: I think that pasting hasn't worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is a workaround. It's not so good but it's very short and it works.*

**Usage**: it's very similar to the usual progress bar, but there are two differences:

1. You should set the bar height, not width
2. Progress bar height is fixed (but it could be changed with inline style)

CSS:

```
.progress-vertical {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px !important;
    position: relative;
}
.progress-vertical .bar {
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
    border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mQzj9/251/

**Edit 1**: Fixed wrong example link.

**Edit 2**: Thanks to Pavlo Mykhalov, the jQuery code is not needed anymore (CSS updated)

**Edit 3**: CSS link outdated, updated.

Comment: Try [`position:absolute` technic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311990/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-float-to-the-bottom-of-its-container) instead of using JavaScript.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov Thanks, but I've already tried, but I can't get it working. Your link is funny because the accepted answer contains "this appears to be impossible" :) If you know how to do it, please improve my code.

Comment: I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQzj9/4/). Now you have to rearrange the gradient from left to right.

Comment: Thank you very much Francesco and PavloMykhalov!