# how to make last image of paragraph be inside of it?

Tags: html, css

i want to put an image in end of a paragraph and want it to be inside paragraph like this image:
[image]

i give float to image but it goes through only one row.

Comment: Good question. I think you'll have to place the image far inside the text so that there is exactly the right amount of text left to the right hand side of the image. I don't know of a solution for this that doesn't require placing the image in the exactly right position

Comment: This is worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311990/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-float-to-the-bottom-of-its-container. Old but good.

Comment: http://bill2me.com/2007/04/18/using-css-to-wrap-text-around-images/

does using float + padding/margin work for you?

Comment: thanks for answers.no, float + margin makes image be on the text not inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately there is no easy way to do this with CSS. As Pekka said, unless you know exactly where to place the image in the markup, you will probably have a bad time.

Comment: Actually, there's _no_ way to do this with just CSS atm.