# how to make a div to float down?

Tags: css, html, alignment, positioning

I have 4 divs. One is outer wrapper, and other 3 are header, content and footer respectively. All the are of same(fixed) width. But height of outer wrapper and content div are variable.

irrespective of the size of these, i want the footer div to stick at the bottom of outer wrapper. I have tried using the following CSS

```
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
```

But it didn't work. Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: What browser are you using? Could you show us an example page? (on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) perhaps?)

Comment: That CSS snippet is saying, "place the bottom border 0x away from (relative to) where it would usually be."

Comment: Do you want the `footer` div to be below the `content` div irrespective of the height of the `wrapper` div, or do you want the `footer` to stick to the bottom of the `wrapper` div irrespective of the height or the `content` div? Just want to know if the height of the `wrapper` div can be greater than the heights of `header` + `content` + `footer` divs?

Comment: 2 similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311990/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-float-to-the-bottom-of-its-container

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To align a div to the bottom, first you have to make the parent div's position relative, then make the required div's position to absolute and set the `bottom` property to zero.

```html
<div style="position: relative; height: 100px; border: solid;">
  <div style="position: absolute; height: 10px; border: solid; bottom: 0; right: 0;  left: 0; ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you mean "make the required div's position to absolute," since you wrote that in your code block?

Answer (score 14):

The *footer div* will need to be either:

- `position:absolute;bottom:0;`; This will push it to the bottom of its container, however, when you scroll down past the container, the footer will scroll with it.
- `position:fixed;bottom:0;`; This is used more often for *sticky* footers. This will place the footer at `bottom:0` of your screen. so no matter where you scroll, what you see is what you get (it will not move around while scrolling)
- `position:relative;bottom:0;`; could be used, but it will be relative to it's siblings (i.e. unless the *content div* is pushing it to the bottom, it won't go there), or, I believe if the container is relative then it may work (but **please** correct me if I'm wrong).

Based on your question: `i want the footer div to stick at the bottom of outer wrapper.` it sounds like you want to use `absolute` positioning for the footer, so that it'll always stick to the bottom of its container....

If you want the footer to stay on the bottom of the screen *no matter where the user scrolls to*, then I'd recommend `fixed` positioning.

Definitely check out [some... tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and most importantly, [mess around and experiment yourself!](http://jsfiddle.net)

you can make us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and maybe it'll shed more light on what you're trying to accomplish. good luck!

Comment: This was a very informative post. I feel like this should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 7):

You can let the wrapper's position is relative and the inner Divs position are absolute.

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 200px">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 20px; background-color:red">
        header
    </div>

    <div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; bottom: 20px; overflow-y: auto">
        content
    </div>

    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; height: 20px; background-color:red">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/YAaA3/

Answer (score 2):

use a clear to get the footer below the content.

simply -

```
#header {
 clear:both;
}
#footer {
 clear: both;
}
```

That should force the header to be on top, and the footer to fall below the floated elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
  <div style="position: relative; height: 10%; top: 90%; ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**UPDATED**]

Here is the `CSS` that **always** sticks the footer to the bottom.

**[**DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/SmEZd/3/)***

CSS-

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#ou {
    position:relative;
    background-color:grey;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto -30px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
#he
{
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
}
#fo{
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 30px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: you are close. There is an issue with this answer. If the content is long then the absolute positioned footer will be above the `content` div. To fix that you can add `padding-bottom: 35px;` to the `content` div and you won't get the footer overlap.

Comment: @sarcastyx: Updated the answer with a solution should work perfect.