# Why div text isn't floating around block?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am so lost.... simpliest task and it just doen't work , i tried everything
Why in this codepen example div block with class float simply doesnt float inside text, i mean why text isnt floating around div ?!?!? 
I tried many variants

https://codepen.io/antongrekov/pen/EBMbbY

tried float: left on **p** tab , float only on block, float on both, clear element, float on container....

```
.wrap
    p lorem lorem ads AsD ADOPF JDS[ FOPSAF S FSD SAD DS DS S DDSDS] lorem lorem ads AsD ADOPF JDS[ FOPSAF S FSD SAD DS DS S DDSDS] lorem lorem ads AsD ADOPF JDS[ FOPSAF S FSD SAD DS DS S DDSDS] lorem lorem ads AsD ADOPF JDS[ FOPSAF S FSD SAD DS DS S DDSDS] lorem lorem ads AsD ADOPF JDS[ FOPSAF S FSD SAD DS DS S DDSDS] lorem lorem ads AsD ADOPF JDS[ FOPSAF S FSD SAD DS DS S DDSDS]
    .float
    .clear
```

```css
.wrap
    background: #333
    border: 3px solid red
    width: 30%
    p
        float: left


    .float
        width: 50px
        height: 50px
        border: 5px solid green
        float: left
    .clear
        clear: both
```

Comment: what i want is to have block at bottom right and text to flow around it.

Comment: because the float is placed **after** the text

Comment: if i put floating block ***before text it goest at top right corner which i dont want. i need it to be at bottom right

Comment: it doesn't work like that.

Comment: This is not possible and is unlikely to ever be - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311990/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-float-to-the-bottom-of-its-container

Comment: Maybe you could upload a photo that illustrates what you're trying to achieve. Might help others provide you with alternative methods

Comment: actually Paulie_D link in your answer contains some solutions to this. I Found one for me there